# Any recommendations for a CSS minifier?

Tags: css, minify

Any recommendations for a CSS minifier?

I’ll be rooting around Google and trying some out, but I suspected that the smart, proficient and curiously handsome StackOverflow community might have already evaluated the pros and cons of the heavyweights.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702907/what-are-some-good-css-and-js-minimizers-for-production-code

Comment: Busted. I’ve been reading ‘How to Make Friends and Influence People’. *Not closely enough though*.

Comment: You guys are all weird. We ARE smart, proficient and curiously handsome.

Comment: I prefer to be called "evil".

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/65491/85414

Comment: Check out the **7 steps solution** described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/11624173/863980

Comment: Not constructive, but 200 upvotes and 47,000 views! BOOYAH!

Comment: (That said, having just listened to [the big closing questions episode of the Stack Exchange podcast](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/07/podcast-50-listen-to-this-podcast/), this question isn’t a good fit for Stack Exchange.)

Comment: I don't understand the overzealous use of "closed as not constructive" on SO. This is a completely reasonable question, and would be objective and suitable for discussion here with just a few small edits.

Comment: @mehaase: I disagree with you that this is a reasonable question. For one, Stack Exchange sites aren't designed for discussion - they're designed for questions and answers. General recommendation/list questions like this are problematic because they're not really answerable - to continue being accurate and avoid being misleading after they're asked, they'd have to be continuously maintained, which the Stack Exchange model doesn't support particularly well.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite "Aren't designed for discussion." I don't think this is a discussion. "They're designed for Q&A". OK, this is a question, and it has answers. How is that not Q&A? "...to continue being accurate" Every question on this site will eventually become inaccurate; technology changes quickly. We seem to handle change pretty well. If the question was edited to read, "What CSS minifier runs on $PLATFORM and meets $TECHNICAL_OBJECTIVES," then it would become a more factual question that elicits more objective answers. So, let's fix it up!

Comment: @mehaase: ah yes - you said 'This is a completely reasonable question, and would be objective and *suitable for discussion here*' (emphasis mine). I was querying that. 'If the question was edited to read, "What CSS minifier runs on $PLATFORM and meets $TECHNICAL_OBJECTIVES," then it would become a more factual question... So, let's fix it up!' - Please do. I didn't have any technical objectives in mind when I wrote it. I just wanted to know what everyone else uses, which led to it being a bad question. I still don't have any technical objectives in mind, so I can't add them.

Comment: +1 just for understanding the 'changing nature' of things around here, and understanding and explaining the reasoning for closing questions like this - even though it's yours! ;)

Comment: I'd look at a [current comparison](https://github.com/GoalSmashers/css-minification-benchmark) of CSS minifiers.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The [YUI Compressor](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/) is fantastic. It works on JavaScript and CSS. Check it out.

Comment: Adding onto this, here is a Makefile which will download the YUI Compressor, pack your files, and minify them.
http://github.com/balupton/jquery-sparkle/blob/9921fcbf1cbeab7a4f2f875a91cb8548f3f65721/Makefile

Comment: http://www.refresh-sf.com/yui/#output

Comment: @JuniorMayhé I used it and my styles got completely messed up though I had checked "Minify only, no symbol obfuscation." option)... sadly every minifier I try always breaks my styles. Is it because online minifiers are all crap? It shouldn't be that way.

Comment: @DiAlex I understand many of them messes with our code, we must use them carefully, always choosing a "conservative" approach and not the aggressive re-factoring. A conservative would be only removing unnecessary spaces, trailing semicolons, duplicate styles, and so on. I think a style could be damaged easily by these minifiers if we use some css hacks inside css code. Backslashes and wierd symbols could drive compressor crazy.

Comment: You can try online service http://www.zbugs.com - it uses yui compressor to minify your files.

Comment: @Buddy, it looks like page you have shared is no longer available. Or the project is closed by Yahoo.

Answer (score 45):

There's also [a .NET port of YUI Compressor](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/) which allows you to:-

- intergrate the minification/file combining into Visual Studio post-build events
- intergrate into a TFS Build (including CI)
- if you wish to just use the dll's in your own code (eg. on the fly minification).

UPDATE 2011: And it's [now available via NuGet](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/YUICompressor.NET) also :)

Comment: I'm a little confused. YUI Compressor is [deprecated](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2012/10/16/state-of-yui-compressor/) in favor of [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) ([demo](http://js-minify.online-domain-tools.com/run/?inputType=text&beautify=0&mangle=1&mangleReservedWords=myLastName&text=var+hello+%3D+function%28myFirstName%2C+myLastName%29+%7B%0A++alert%28%22Hello+%22+%2B+myFirstName+%2B+%27+%27+%2B+myLastName%29%3B%0A%7D%3B%0Ahello%28%22John%22%2C+%22Smith%22%29%3B)). Does it make a sense to work on a .NET port?

Comment: Mate. I started that port in 2008 or so. That's 6 odd years ago. I also posted this answer in '09.  So please check the dates and get some context before you ask silly q's. Now, go outside and play for a wee bit :)

Comment: Pure.Krome: I beg to differ. I have looked at the GitHub repo and it is a few months old and the commits are from this year. That's why I asked. "Mate".

Comment: :slow clap: well spotted! you're actually righ--- oh. Wait. I started the proj on codeplex: http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/. First commit July 7 2008 (http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/b437de1e033c2703adbed8433e3bd5b4f630e126). Then moved it to GH _this year_. I've not done any work on porting it for a.long.time. There's only been a few odd bug fixes here and there. So. Dude. I port*ED* it. Not port*ing* it. It's in maintenance mode. Q.E.D.

Comment: You too :) And cheers for the link to UglifyJS - that was something i've been meaning to check out to see if we can use it at work - and you've just reminded us about it! cheers :)

Answer (score 19):

I like [Minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/). In PHP and works with CSS or JavaScript.

Comment: +1 for Minify. If you are familiar with PHP already you may be more comfortable installing it. Requires PHP5. Once you set it up you can forget about it, work as normal on as many super white-spaced and commented css or js files as you want and minify will compress them on the fly.

Answer (score 14):

[CSSO](https://github.com/css/csso) is currently best minifier/optimizer.

Comment: Dunno about “the best”, but worth a look.

Comment: Just try it and you'll find it is the best. There is no analogs for its minification technics for this moment as I know.

Comment: alrighty, I’ve compared CSSO to YUI Compressor on a 30 KB test file, and after gzipping the compressed output of both tools, CSSO wins, having compressed the file by an extra 7 bytes. That’s just one test file though of course.

Comment: reduce CSS online with CSSO: http://css.github.io/csso/csso.html

Comment: At least it's one of the two recommended by [Google PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/MinifyResources).

Answer (score 8):

If you use Python I would recommend [slimmer](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/slimmer/) which is probably not as fast as YUI Compressor but unlike csscompressor.net it doesn't choke on CSS hacks.

I'm biased since I wrote slimmer and I'm currently evaluating YUI Compressor to see how it handles hacks. An example of slimmer in action can be seen if you view the source of crosstips.org

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for an online tool, try this: https://csscompressor.net/

Comment: I wish I could down vote this answer (its already too late after i upvoted it). I'm trying to compress my css and it breaks things. That isn't good at all. Warning to everyone out there, my guess is that unless you have pristine standards compliant css, it might break your shit!

Comment: But, *shouldn't* *you* have pristine, standards compliant CSS?

Comment: if you're using HTML5 boilerplate, nope.

Comment: Nice tool. I've tested it on `html{width:100%;height:100%;} body{width:100%;height:100%;padding:0;} #test{padding:1em;width:10em;} #test{padding:2em;}` and it did better job than YUI Compressor (which didn't eliminate duplicates for #test's padding). Still, both failed to satisfy me with `html,body{width:100%;height:100%}body{padding:0}` (which, in my understanding, is equivalent, as both selectors have same specificity).

Comment: CSS is the one thing where crappy hacks are sometimes acceptable.  Some of those hacks use weird comment tricks that minifiction can break.

Comment: I personally use [CompressCSS](https://compresscss.net/). It uses clean-css and very safe to use.

Answer (score 6):

Check out CSSTidy: http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/usage.php

And online at: http://cdburnerxp.se/cssparse/css_optimiser.php

Comment: A modified online version that supports CSS3 is available at http://devilo.us

Answer (score 4):

I've written an ultra fast CSS minifier in C#. The algorithm does not handle Javascript though. Thy this: http://www.ko-sw.com/Blog/post/An-Ultra-Fast-CSS-Minify-Algorithm.aspx.

Comment: Nice-looking option. One query though: you said “According to the CSS specification, two types of strings are supported: single-quoted and double-quoted. My algorithm leaves the string intact, even if whitespace characters are found inside it... I just think that keeping the string unmodified is more intuitive and professional.” Surely any space characters that don’t add meaning should be removed, to make the output file as small as possible? Isn’t that the point of minification?

Comment: Well, in my opinion this is surely right in a general case. But I consider strings a special case. It is up to the developer of the original CSS whether or not to remove meaningless whitespace from strings. The algorithm I'm showing simply follows the specification keeping the string unmodified.

Answer (score 4):

Try [closure-stylesheets](http://code.google.com/p/closure-stylesheets).

Beside **minification** it also supports **linting**, **RTL flipping**, and **class renaming**.

It can also add **variables**, **functions**, **conditionals**, and **mixins** to CSS.

Also note that some of these features depend on rest of [Closure Tools](https://developers.google.com/closure) (which are very powerful on their own).

Comment: how do you use it on windows? forgive my ignorance

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for something in PHP, here's the link:-

[Fat-Free Minify](http://razorsharpcode.blogspot.com/2010/02/lightweight-javascript-and-css.html)

Although it's part of the PHP Fat-Free Framework, it can also be used stand-alone.

Comment: The Fat Free Framework is GPL and thus I assume this part of their code is too. Just a head ups.

Comment: It has bugs :S bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

I find that isnoop's [CSS SuperScrub](http://isnoop.net/tools/css.php) works very well.  It can only handle direct links to CSS online though :/  You can get around that though by using your preferred pastebin service to hold the css code and just giving SuperScrub the raw link.

Comment: I've tried it on `#test { padding: 1em; width: 10em; } #test { padding: 2em; }` and it failed.

Comment: @drdaeman That's probably because it doesn't know what to do with conflicting/duplicate values for a given selector. Since I don't maintain SuperScrub, I can't tell you when or if that will be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

If your site is in ASP.NET, you can let your site do the CSS minification on the fly (so you don't have to do it manually each time you make a change). For example with this:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CombineAndMinify.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Still "in beta", but should work fairly well. I use the code behind it in every project: http://claudiu.phpfogapp.com/ It's built in PHP and also hosts your *.css file for a fairly large amount of time, surely enough to let you test your code with the minified css. (I would only delete old css files if the space gets crowded on the server).

Answer (score 3):

Perl has [CSS::Minifier](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CSS%3a%3aMinifier) (and an XS version for extra speed).

Answer (score 3):

Others have mentioned YUI Compressor, then the .NET port of it, and I'll add another link to the chain. [StyleManager](http://www.gstylemanager.com) is a server control which wraps up the .NET port of YUI Compressor so you can use it just like you're used to using ScriptManager. It adds a bunch of other nice features too, like CSS constants, tilde (~) resolution w/in your background-image definitions, etc etc. It's tight, well documented, and I've used it on all my recent projects w/o an issue. Check it out - [gStyleManager.com](http://www.gstylemanager.com)

Answer (score 2):

An online tool (much better than www.csscompressor.net which jacked my css up): http://www.cssdrive.com/compressor/compress.php does an excellent job.

Comment: Has bugs. In specific situations it breaks perfectly good js code

Answer (score 2):

There is a codeplex project that will plug in to .net websites that will minify and compress the CSS and the JS files.  There is also a comparison between the Microsoft AJAX Minifier and the YUI Compressor which shows the YUI coming out slightly better.  There is an extra variation which combines the Microsoft Minifier and compression which drastically srunk the file.

Anyway the link is 
http://xpedite.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Minifier%20(CSS%2FJavaScript%20Minification%20Handlers)

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it for MVC3:
http://mkramar.blogspot.com/2011/08/css-and-javascript-minify-and-combine.html
The beauty of this approach is that it does it all on the fly and you don't have to pre-process files manually or configure post-build.

Answer (score 1):

C# example:

```
css = css.Replace("\n", "");
css = Regex.Replace(css, @"\s+", " ");
css = Regex.Replace(css, @"\s*:\s*", ":");
css = Regex.Replace(css, @"\s*\,\s*", ",");
css = Regex.Replace(css, @"\s*\{\s*", "{");
css = Regex.Replace(css, @"\s*\}\s*", "}");
css = Regex.Replace(css, @"\s*\;\s*", ";");
```

Answer (score 1):

[zbugs.com](http://www.zbugs.com) will be a good online tool for you, it will minify your css in a single click

Comment: Sure, although I don’t think there are many minifiers that require more than one click to start them.

Comment: You right Paul :) but this one does a lot more then just minify, and all in single click

Answer (score 1):

Have a peek at the latest [HTML5BoilerPlate](https://github.com/paulirish/html5-boilerplate) by Paul Irish - it contains a build script to minify all your assets (including PNG's and JPG's). You can see a demo video [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OXpCB3U_4Ig).

Comment: Sure; its CSS minifier is YUI Compressor though.