# Offline CSS compressor

Tags: css, minify

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any recommendations for a CSS minifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787789/any-recommendations-for-a-css-minifier)

I am looking for a css compressor that can run on our build server that can be executed on a number of css files. Does anyone know of any good ones that work offline?

Comment: Check out the wro4j tool: http://alexo.github.com/wro4j/

Comment: Check out the **7 steps solution** described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/11624173/863980

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look at [Yahoo! UI Library](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/)? This provides an programmable (.NET) CSS compressor (as well as an Javascript compressor).

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, the [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) by Yahoo! is a Java utility that works offline. It's very good and handles both JavaScript and CSS files.

Comment: Damn it, second time to be a few seconds too late with the same answer ;)

Comment: "The YUI Compressor is fantastic. It works on javascript and css. Check it out.".. this is from the duplicate, a little bit of intellectual honesty please :)

Comment: @Jack: Are you insinuating that I looked up an existing answer and rewrote it here to gain reputation? Perhaps I just knew it because I'm a web developer? Look up my answer history, you'll find at least a hundred accepted answers related to web development. Please don't assume things about people unless you're sure about it.

Comment: I didn't accuse anyone. But I don't see any effort in looking for a duplicate for a question already asked FOR SURE before channeling all your developer powers to answer him.

Comment: Well, I use this site for my own interests. And when I stumble upon a question I can answer, I answer it. People interested in moderation (like you, obviously) are welcome to moderate the question if it is a duplicate, but I don't feel obligated to do so. So still, I don't see what I did wrong.

Comment: Thanks, had to mark, Marc as the correct answer though. He had it 1 min before you did.

Comment: Actually he posted 1 minute after, but it's okay :) Note that his link goes to a .NET library while mine is to a Java library. If you're on a Windows environment, both should work, but the Java one is more cross-platform.