# Is there an advanced CSS minifier/compiler that does things like strip redundancy and comma separate identical rules?

Tags: css, compiler-construction, minify

For example

```
input{margin:0}body{margin:0;background:white}
```

would be shorter written like this

```
input,body{margin:0}body{background:white}
```

or this

```
input,body{margin:0}body{margin:0;padding:0}
```

would be shorter written like this

```
input,body{margin:0}body{padding:0}
```

<strike>**Conclusion** no such tool</strike> See the accepted answer.

**A tip to the tool writers**, you **may** want to consider gzip. Sometimes, leaving a few bytes on a second-rate optimization will be shorter in the end because gzip is essentially byte-level deduplication. If there are two identical sections, gzip will reference the earlier one. **Ideally** this would be considered in deciding if certain optimizations should be skipped some or all of the time, and what the order of the selectors and rules should be.

Comment: Yep, but I charge $30 / hour.

Comment: Always meaning to write a tool to do that...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This can be done using [CSSO](http://css.github.com/csso/csso.html).

Consider the following input:

```
input{margin:0}body{margin:0;background:white}
```

CSSO output:

```
input,body{margin:0}body{background:#fff}
```

*(exactly what you are looking for)*

<s>But unfortunately, CSSO optimize this:</s>

```
.dont-care {
    background-image: url("images/chart.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

To:

```
.dont-care{background-image:url("images/chart.png");background-repeat:no-repeat}
```

However, [CSSTidy](http://cdburnerxp.se/cssparse/css_optimiser.php) converts the above to the corresponding shorthand property:

```
.dont-care {
    background:url("images/chart.png") no-repeat;
}
```

**<s>Seven</s> Four steps solution for optimizing CSS:**
Here is the practice I follow:

1. Merge CSS files in `all.css`.
2. Supply to [CSSO](http://css.github.com/csso/csso.html) input.
3. Hit <kbd>Minimize</kbd>
4. Paste the output in `all.min.css`

Except paying @Grillz to get it done manually, I haven't found a better deal for CSS optimization thus far..

**But what about old IE hacks?**
If you are using CSS hacks for IE6 and 7, CSSO will preserve the hacks.

For example:

```
.dont-care {
    background-image: url("images/chart.png");
    *background-image: url("images/chart.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

CSSO output:

```
.dont-care{background-image:url("images/chart.png");*background-image:url("images/chart.jpg");background-repeat:no-repeat}
```

<s>CSSTidy will ignore asterik(* hack used for IE6), and output:</s>

```
.dont-care {
    background:url("images/chart.jpg") no-repeat;
}
```

You can also avoid hacks and use separate CSS file for older IE versions (say all.oldIE.css). After optimizing (using 7 steps described earlier) both files separately, this is what you may use in the <head> tag of your HTML/masterpage/template/layout file eventually:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]><link href="css/all.oldIE.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><![endif]--> 
<!--[if gt IE 7]><!--><link href="css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><!--<![endif]-->
```

where `all.min.css` would work for all browsers except IE versions less than and equal to 7. But using CSSO alone is a safe bet.

## Update

Skip the CSSTidy part. CSSO does safe optimization. [According to their developer](https://github.com/css/csso/issues/75#issuecomment-7452458), shorthand optimization is not safe:

> Consider that example:

```
.a{
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
.b {
    background-image: url("images/chart.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

> and if you'd have `<div class="a b"></div>` — an element with both
>   classes, you can't optimize the .b as you write, 'cause it would
>   override the `background-attachment` set in .a. 
>   So, no, that's not a safe optimization.

Comment: Thank you for explaining why automatic shorthanding can't be done.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at CSS Tidy, it can do some merging: http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Their feature list does not seem to work on the level I described (I don't blame them, I had little expectation to find such a tool anywhere except by converting an entire project to GWT.)

Answer (score 2):

If you use visual studio, you could install the [Web Essentials](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ed4c78f-a23e-49ad-b5fd-369af0c2107f) extension. It has
experimental support for cleaning and merging CSS rules, but not exactly like you subscribed.
It, for one, creates more whitespace, but it does combine css tags, that have (partially) equal styles eg..

Answer (score 2):

try LESS.

LESS will automatically recognizes when you save your `*.less` file and immediately compiles your CSS-Code and will minified. You can create as many files as you want and LESS will observe them all to trigger compilation.

You will only work in the `.less` files. the Tool will auto compile and save you files as `.css`

http://lesscss.org/

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend 
[https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-clean-css](http://gulp-clean-css)

if you don't have problems using gulp
it's doing exactly as you want

Answer (score 1):

<del>Yes, there is. The [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) does this for you.</del> I was wrong, the YUI Compressor is only a minifier, but indeed very useful. What and how they minify is [presented here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/css.html).

This is a .jar package that you'll have to [download](http://yuilibrary.com/downloads/#yuicompressor) and then run through the terminal, if you're on Unix or Linux (I don't know about Windows, so someone fill this gap!), with the following syntax:

```
$ java -jar /path/to/yuicompressor-x.y.z.jar myfile.css -o myfile-min.css
```

The `-o` option declares what file you wish to write your minified content to.

Comment: YUI doesn't re-write rules and combine like rules as the OP is asking.   It does do generic minification (did I just invent a word there?), but that's not what he was asking if I understood correctly)...

Comment: irc is correct. This only seems to handle basic optimizations such as whitespace and comments. Also the command you displayed is the same on Windows if you add Java's bin to the `PATH`. If not you have to specify the full path to the exe file in double quotes `"C:\Program Files\Java\...\bin\java.exe" -jar ...`

Answer (score 1):

May be the wrong thing, but h[ttp://www.cleancss.com/](http://www.cleancss.com/)?

Comment: That is close. At least they convert `form{margin:0}body{margin:0}` into `form,body{margin:0}`. It also shortens color names (`#FF0000` is shorter as `red`). It does not handle of the examples in the question.

Comment: CleanCSS.com is based on an old version of CSS Tidy. Found a site running the latest version via Google: http://cdburnerxp.se/cssparse/css_optimiser.php

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such tool which optimizes to the level you ask (that I'm aware of at least), and I'm not sure you'd want to use it if there was.  The reason is that it's not a trivial problem to find the *smallest* possible minified css code.  For the trivial CSS you provided, it's easy.  But imagine doing that on a 300kb block of CSS.  It's not trivial.  And is it worth wasting the CPU time generating it (it might be if you're caching the results, but it won't be if you're serving it dynamically)?

And what's the gain?  Saving a few percent at most on the transfer?  Unless you have facebook level traffic, you're not going to save much bandwidth.  And a few percent isn't going to impact your users much either (even over dial-up, transferring a few kb isn't that bad).

Just use a standard compressor ([minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/), [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/), etc) and be done with it.  Instead, worry about the low hanging fruit.  The easy to fix problems...

Comment: The plan is to cache the minified and gzipped versions of all CSS and JavaScript on all apps assuming they have a single commented out line that says it is OK to do so (not trying to debug code). Also this is for obfuscation in order to make our code harder to run off with. The CPU would only happen once for every change to the file. This handling would be on the webserver level which will be replicated to many servers. - - - So if there was one available,, I would use it. Although we don't have FaceBook level traffic, we do like to keep our code from getting out.

Comment: @George: for obfuscation or keeping your code from getting out, this is not the right way.  That's a separate problem (which I would argue isn't possible to solve in this case), so it should likely be treated as such...

Answer (score 1):

have you tried [less.js](http://lesscss.org/index.html) ?
you can write css code  in an object oriented manner, also you can use this framework either on client side or server side, below a demonstration on your case:

```
/* you can write you desired css as follows */
body {
  &input {
        margin: 0;
  }
  background:white;
}
```

and it will be automatically compiled into:

```
body, input {
    margin:0;
}

body {
    background:white;
}
```

Comment: Looks pretty good so far, but I cannot fully test right now because in order to output plain CSS I have to use Node JS. Using the browser seems to just call the generated CSS without actually outputting it to the screen. I will get around to this eventually.

Comment: Instead of embedding the less.js directly, you could use WinLESS/Less.app (Win/Mac) to watch the directory where you store your .less files. It will automatically convert it into .css for you (and the apps should even have options for better compression)

Answer (score 1):

Ther are several out there.  Some of the best ones are;

http://refresh-sf.com/yui/

http://www.minifycss.com/css-compressor/

The second one groups rules that match together also and more.

Answer (score 1):

CSSO is little bit outdated, ACCSS is a port CSSO to but fixes open issues of the original code.

https://github.com/acwtools/accss

and it also has a better compression ratio