# Is there something like jsmin for css?

Tags: css, compression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any recommendations for a CSS minifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787789/any-recommendations-for-a-css-minifier)

JsMin is a compression and combination executable for javascript files.  Is there something like that for CSS files?

Comment: I think Stackoverflow may need to update their question search.  When I typed in the question originally, the "duplicate" mentioned above was not listed.

Answer (score 3):

Google #1 result for CSS compression: http://www.refresh-sf.com/yui/

Comment: As my question asked, I was looking for an executable (not a web site that does it for me).

Answer (score 1):

CSS cannot be minified in the same way that JavaScript can. You can replace variables such as `lastItemRead` with names like `a`, but in CSS you cannot replace selectors like `.lastItemRead` with shorter selectors (not without crawling through and rewriting your entire site).

That being said, you can remove white-space and comments from CSS files. There are several tools that exist for doing this - the [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) is a popular option from Yahoo!.

There's a lot you yourself can do also to keep your CSS files lightweight. Remove unused selectors, reduce redundancy, and try to join many rules:

```
background-color:red;
background-image:url(stars.png);
background-position:center center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

Is a bit verbose; better to write it as:

```
background:red url(stars.png) center center no-repeat;
```

Saves a tremendous amount of space. Another thing to look out for is adding unnecessary characters to rules. For instance, when you are setting paddings and margins, there's no need to add a unit after your 0 values:

```
margin:0px 10px; /* 0px should be 0 */
```

A lot of this stuff can be fleshed out by using a great tool like the CSSLint, online at http://csslint.net/. Warning: *CSSLint will hurt your feelings!*

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can visit this :

http://lesscss.org/