# Is it possible to condense/minify AppleScript code?

Tags: applescript, minify, yui-compressor

I know you can [minify/condense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787789/any-recommendations-for-a-css-minifier) Javascript or CSS code, but can you do this with AppleScript?

Comment: I'm not sure (I don't have my Mac handy to test), but I imagine it would all come down to whether or not the carriage return is meaningful in the language.  You can probably test it by writing a simple script, minifying by hand, and seeing if it works.  If it does, you can probably write an AppleScript program to minify other AppleScript programs :)  (Keeping in mind that probably every development tool will try to un-minify (or re-bigulate) it for you.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, line feeds are the equivalent of the semicolon in C.  You can use the "Chevron" syntax though.

```
on run
    main()
end run

on main()
    tell application "Finder"
        display dialog "Hi."
    end tell
end main
```

converts to:

```
on «event aevtoapp»
    main()
end «event aevtoapp»

on main()
    tell «class capp» "Finder"
        «event sysodlog» "Hi."
    end tell
end main
```

There is no enbiggening or rebigulation here, this is actually the raw syntax of the AppleScript.  I used the Script Debugger app to switch between the two syntaxes.