# When is a font file fetched when imported inside a CSS media query?

Tags: css, media-queries, font-face

If I import Google font CSS inside a `@media print` section, when will browsers fetch the font files? Only when printing? Or more eagerly?

```
@media print {
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mate');
    ...
}
```

I'm wondering if users will get a download penalty even when they are not printing.

I've tried to search and can't seem to find an answer. When I used Chrome Dev Tools, it didn't seem to fetch the font at all! I think because I already have it installed locally.

Comment: Based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551049/css-mediaqueries-defining-font-face-inside-a-certain-min-to-max-range-is-this) I would guess that it would be eager loaded.  But I could be wrong.