# WordPress - CSS importing is not working for me

Tags: php, css, wordpress, themes

I'm a WordPress n00b. I can't seem to get simple CSS imported into my page.

This is my that I've tried:

index.php

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

style.css

```
/* External */
@import: url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela');
@import: url('https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css');

/* Internal */
@import: url('css/bootstrap.css');
@import: url('css/custom-styles.css');
```

I've also tried:

index.php:

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

and this just to be double sure:

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('style.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I've done researching but I can't find anything other than what I've tried above. So I appologize if this is a repeat.

EDIT:

This doesn't work within WordPress within the index.php:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css">
<link href="css/custom-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: I rolled back your revision because you removed the problem code from your question. In order for the answer below to make sense, the colons are necessary in your question.

Comment: Are you sure those file-paths are correct?

Comment: @David I'm pretty sure. The only things I changed from the working static html site was adding the link to style.css and changing the file extension from .html to .php

Answer (score 5):

You're doing this the wrong way for wordpress.  You should be enqueing your stylesheet.  THe following should go in your functions.php file.

```
function enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
}
```

If you are using hard coded links as in your example, these should be added to header.php, however this is bad practice as Wordpress has it's own way to handle dependencies and conflicts.

Check out the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style)

Also, as already mentioned, it's generally bad practice to use @import to load multiple style sheets.  You can use enqueue to load in all these scripts, just make sure the scripts you need to have precendence are loaded last:

```
    function enqueue_styles() {
 wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesheet', 'netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css');
 wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesheet', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela');
 wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array() );
 wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
 wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom-styles.css');
    }
```

And hook it like so:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_styles' );
```

Comment: Okay. So I would duplicate the last line in your function to add multiple styles? What about styles not located on the server, those too?

Comment: @dustindowell22 edited to show how to load everything.

Comment: Thanks. Now I just need to figure out how to include the functions.php.

Comment: You don't need to include it.  It's a default wordpress file, and should be located in the top directory of your theme.  If it's not there, just create a file called functions.php and wordpress will automatically load it.

Comment: Okay. That's what I did, but it's just spitting out all of the code at the top of the page. EDIT: Sorry, forgot <?php tags. Woops.

Comment: Beat me to it.  Was about to give you the tags :)

Comment: Still not working for some reason though. All that gets rendered to the HTML is an empty <style></style> tag. And no error in the console mentioning not being able to find the CSS.

Comment: That's very strange.  Can you link to your site?  Have you viewed the source to see if wordpress is loading?

Comment: Oops! just realised I forgot to include the hook in the above tag, so your function is not being called.  JUst copy and paste add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts_and_styles' );

Comment: Sorry, I can't link you right now. I'm working locally on MAMP and I'm currently working out issues with my hosting company about installing WordPress on a server.

Comment: Thanks for working with me on this. But I'm getting the same result.

Comment: Try this instead  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_styles' );

Comment: Yup. I've been experimenting with those names too. No progress :C.

Comment: It should be throwing an error if your'e calling a function that doesn't exist.  Try adding test();  to see if you get an error.

Comment: Well your functions.php file is not loading, so there is something wrong with your setup.  If you move to chat, I'll try to help you with this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51912/discussion-between-dustindowell22-and-talk-nerdy-to-me)

Comment: Not sure you need `global $wp_styles;` in your `enqueue_styles()` function?

Comment: @Talknerdytome you have a syntax error in your code. Check here `wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . 'css/custom-styles.css');`. Forgot `/` before `css/custom-styles.css`

Comment: @Talknerdytome great answer, +1. Also +1 for the update.

Answer (score 2):

You should not have a colon after your import statement:

```
@import url("css/bootstrap.css");
```

---

That being said, what you are doing is typically rendered as **bad practice**. CSS files should never import other CSS if they can help it as it requires you to download the files synchronously:

> I download styles.css
>
> ---->Then download bootstrap.css because it is imported.

It is much better to import both directly in the HTML document:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css"/>
```

[**See this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036977/best-way-to-include-css-why-use-import) for more info.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't used imports in a long time. Though, I'm still having issues. I'd much rather just import them into the HTML, though, I read that this is more common with WordPress?

Comment: As I said above, it is common to import all of your stylesheets directly into the HTML as it allows you to download them asynchronously. It is not only common amongst wordpress, but among all websites.

Comment: @dustindowell22 If it still doesn't work, then it must be the file paths. It's worth noting that paths are relative to the source of the style sheet, not relative to the document.

Comment: @JoshCrozier I've edited my main post when I tried importing the CSS directly into the index.php page. This is the first time I tried, and I just assumed it was the wrong way for WordPress themes.

I'm 100% sure path names are correct.

Comment: @dustindowell22 Can you provide a link to the website where you are trying to import the CSS?