# I am using redhat, Mox_proxy working but links on page wont work for tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, redhat

I am using Redhat Linux, with apache, tomcat, and alfresco.

I have successfully used a virtual server with proxypass and proxypassreverse to have example.com as the  servername for port 8282. I am sent to tomcat, and I can see the beginning tomcat page just fine, however links i am using will not work. tomcat is running alfresco, and i type example.com/share/page/ and it sends me to the login page, however it looks as if any css that was used to style the page is gone, and the textboxes to type username and password are off to the side. If i type the actual ip address and port number,/share/page/ the page works fine.

Not sure why this is not working

```
http://example1/share/page/
```

when

```
http://<ip-address>:8282/share/page/
```

works

Here is my code in /tomcat/conf/server.xml

```
<Connector className="org.alfresco.share"
            port="8282"
        proxyName="example1"
        proxyPort="80"/>
```

Here is my code in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName     example1
     ProxyPass  /  http://<ip-address>:8282/
     ProxyPassReverse  /  http://<ip-address>:8282/
</VirtualHost>
```

I have tried this on another server with apache-tomcat-8.0.9, without alfresco, and it worked.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution, I looked at the code and found that the code for alfresco was using @import and the server, or browser was just taking a while to load. this is the first problem That I have solved without changed a single line of code.
Here is the link [Best way to include CSS? Why use @import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036977/best-way-to-include-css-why-use-import)