# How Do You Add a Query String That Automatically Updates to a CSS File Included in Another CSS File via the @import Rule?

Tags: html, css, caching, browser-cache

I've got one CSS file included in a larger CSS file via the @import rule. The larger CSS file has a query string that gets automatically updated via a plugin for the CMS we use. However, the query string only forces the browser to reload the main CSS file and not the imported one.

Is there a way to have the @imported CSS file, embedded within the other CSS file, get an automatically updated query string?

Thanks!

Comment: ahhhh don't embed the other CSS file with `@import`! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036977/best-way-to-include-css-why-use-import