# How should i include css files in .vue files?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, normalize, vue-cli

I'm using official vue-cli scaffolder and trying to include normalize.css in App.vue this way

```
<style scoped>
  @import "/node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css";
  .app {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    text-align: center;
    color: #2c3e50;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
  }
</style>
```

But after compiling css doesn't include in style tag or as external file:

[image]

So, how can I correctly include this or another css file?

Answer (score 1):

Your style tag does not have a `lang` attribute, which implies that when the Vue components are bundled it will output a plain CSS file: no pre-processing.

When this happens it'll move your import statement and convert it to a [plain CSS import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@import).

To fix your code, you'll want to change your import URL to a relative path accessible to the web server. In your case, the path `/node_modules` is not mounted on the web server so it won't resolve the file. It's probably easier ([and better practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10037064/2748736)) to either put normalize in a different style tag on the page (with HTTP2 this will not be a bottleneck), or use a pre-processor and import normalize into the same final output as your CSS.

If you want to use SASS/SCSS as a pre-processor (your syntax is valid SCSS already), then you'll want to define your styles like so:

`<style lang="scss" scoped>`

The Webpack `vue-loader` will support a number of languages, but you'll also need to add the correct Webpack loader for the pre-processor:

`npm i --save-dev node-sass sass-loader`

More information on the Vue Webpack loader with CSS can be found [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/blob/master/docs/en/configurations/pre-processors.md#using-pre-processors)