# Regroup all CSS link in one line

Tags: html, css

In my `HYML` page I have the following `CSS` Link

**myPage.html**

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i"
rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
rel="stylesheet">
<link
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
rel="stylesheet"
integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB"
crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css"
integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg"
crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto"
rel="stylesheet">
```

Is there a way to regroup this link in one and call it instead of using all this code line?

Comment: [@import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import). Use with caution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036977/best-way-to-include-css-why-use-import

Comment: https://www.os-templates.com/journal/cascading-style-sheets/using-at-import-to-call-your-css-files

Comment: @Sparky this is exactly what i am looking for thank you

Comment: No problem. Mark it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For marking it as answer.

Look at [this page](https://www.os-templates.com/journal/cascading-style-sheets/using-at-import-to-call-your-css-files) and you'll find anything you need.

*Content summary of the link attached*

```
<style type="text/css">
    @import url("main.css");
</style>
```

Where **main.css** contains:

```
@import "file1.css";
@import "file2.css";
@import "file3.css";
@import "file4.css";
@import "file5.css";
```

these are the name of the files.

Comment: I am testing it and if worked (i don't no why not) i will make it as an answer thank you

Comment: After testing it's worked for me +1 (why not upvote the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @import statement in your main css file.
Not sure if this will work with FontAwesome though.

You also import the font family 'Roboto' multiple times and FontAwesome as well. Is that intended?

Comment: it was in test purpose