# Load all css as a single http request and minified form?

Tags: php, html, css, http, minify

I need to compress my css files and presently it takes lot of time for loading and i also got multiple http request warning.

So i found this on code.google.com 
[Code.google.com example program link](https://code.google.com/p/fastcssloader/)

according to them,i need to specify all css links in a php file instead of my html and call that php once in html.So the http request issue will get solved and that code from google compress the css file also.

```
Instead of

link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css" />
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/menu.css" />
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/blog.css" />
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/box.css" />
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/form.css" />
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/profile.css" />
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/page.css" />
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/gallery.css" />

Your write

link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/css_include.php" />
```

This is the php code format

```
<?php

function compress($buffer) 
{
    $buffer = preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $buffer);

    $buffer = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t", '  ', '    ', '    '), '', $buffer);

    return $buffer;
}

$handle = opendir(".");

header  ('Content-type: text/css');
header  ("Cache-control: public");
header  ("Vary: Accept-Encoding");
header  ("Content-Encoding: gzip");

ob_start("ob_gzhandler");

while (false != ($file = readdir($handle))) 
{
    if (strpos($file,".css") !== FALSE)
    {
        echo compress (file_get_contents($file));
    }
}

?>
```

But My question is how can i add files in that php ???I mean where should i add the css paths in this php?

Comment: here is an answer which might help you out aswell. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17433011/3679632

Comment: That is actually another way, but i like to how can i add css files in php code. I mean where should i add the css paths in this php?

Comment: but if import ,it will still call it as separate urls ryt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$handle = opendir(".");` will read all files in the current directory. So just change that to wherever your css files are i.e. `opendir("/var/www/css")`

Or place the php file in your css directory

Comment: do i need to add like  opendir("/css/style.css"); opendir("/css/design.css");   or simply  just that directory name  opendir("/css")

Comment: don't add the name of a specific file, add the name of the path that the files are in

Comment: one more doubt , will it reduce my number of http request made for css ?

Comment: yes, instead of 1 http call per css you will just make 1 http call to the php file which will return 1 large combined css

Comment: ok. do you know any good document for this , i mean to learn more?

Comment: Not specifically for this but you could read about the functions used (i.e. `opendir`, `readdir`, `ob_start`) at php.net

Comment: Do u know which is the best way or which plugin most of applications are using.