# Is there a shorthand for multiple link-elements?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I'm just wondering if there's a way to link multiple css-files to one html-file without having to write down every link like below?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/alla.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/meny.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/fotografier.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/footer.css">
```

Comment: Something like this? [calling multiple external css files at once to html page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432929/calling-multiple-external-css-files-at-once-to-html-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge them into one, there are multiple tools to do that:

1. http://www.shrinker.ch/
2. https://github.com/zenorocha/browser-diet/wiki/Tools#css