# How to arrange css code

Tags: css

I want to arrange css code. My code is:

```
.fb_icon{height:30px; width:50px; background:#FFF; margin:0 0 0 700px;}
.fb_img{height:30px; width:50px;}
```

I don't want any space in my css file. Please help me. Thanks for great help.

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific if you want to avoid having your question closed. What do you mean by arrange? There's already just about as little space as possible in the overwhelming two lines of CSS you posted.

Comment: I have found a website that can help you to remove it. Here is the link: http://textmechanic.co/Remove-Extra-Spaces.html

Comment: Any CSS minifier would do. Perhaps you just didn't know what tool to google for?

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be asking about the "minifier" concept.

Here are a few options:

- http://cssminifier.com/
- http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/
- [Stackoverflow Quesiton 787789: recommendations for a css minifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787789/any-recommendations-for-a-css-minifier)

Answer (score 0):

How to arrange CSS code:

Before:

```
.fb_icon{height:30px; width:50px; background:#FFF; margin:0 0 0 700px;}
.fb_img{height:30px; width:50px;}
```

After:

```
.fb_icon {
    height:30px;
    width:50px;
    background:#FFF;
    margin:0 0 0 700px;
}

.fb_img {
    height:30px;
    width:50px;
}
```

Other possibility:

```
.fb_icon{height:30px;width:50px;background:#FFF;margin:0 0 0 700px;}
.fb_img{height:30px;width:50px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
.fb_icon{height:30px;width:50px;background:#FFF;margin:0 0 0 700px}.fb_img{height:30px;width:50px}
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you didn't explain your code. If you do explain this code (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes—and the questioner actually learns something!