# How can I clean this CSS code; making it shorter or delete unnecessary parts (CSS perfectionist needed)

Tags: css

How can I clean this CSS code: making it shorter, nesting properties together, deleting unnecessary code, etc.

```
/* reset */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
body { line-height: 1; }
ol, ul { list-style: none; }
blockquote, q { quotes: none; }
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
:focus { outline: 0; } /* remember to define focus styles! */
ins { text-decoration: none; } /* remember to highlight inserts somehow! */
del { text-decoration: line-through; } /* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
/* tags */
body {
    background: #F9F9F9;
    color: #888;
    font-family: Arial, "微软雅黑", "MS Trebuchet", sans-serif;
    font-size: 75%
}
h1 {
    font-size: 32px;
}
h2 {
    /*color: #999;*/
    color: #999;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
p {
    line-height: 160%;
}
a {
    color: #69C;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
/* structure */
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 15px;
    width: 960px;
}
/* header */
#header {
    background: #EEE;
}
#header h1 {
    float: left;
}
#header h1 a {
    background: url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 500px;
}
/* banner */
#header-top {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
    padding: 0 0 15px 0;
    margin: 30px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 960px; /* ie6 hack */
}
#lang {
    float: right;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}
#lang li {
    float: left;
}
#lang li a {
    font-size: 10px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}
#lang li a.current {
    color: #888;
}
/* intro */
#header-bottom {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 0 30px 0;
}
#tagline {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 40px 0 0;
    width: 540px; /* 560 */
}
#tagline h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
}
#tagline h2 strong {
    /*color: #69C;*/
}
#about {
    float: right;
    width: 380px;
}
/* work */
#content {
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
}
.showcase {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
    margin: 30px 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 0 30px;
    width: 960px; /* ie hack */
}
.showcase div.right {
    display: inline; /* ie hack */
    float: left;
}
.showcase div.left {
    display: inline; /* ie hack */
    float: left;
    height: 211px;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 290px;
}
.showcase div img {
    border: 2px solid #EEE;
    width: 630px;
    height: 190px;
    padding: 8px;
}
.showcase div img:hover {
    border: 2px solid #CDE;
}
.showcase div p {
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
.showcase div ul#sites {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 160%;
}
.showcase div ul#sites li {
    float: left;
}
.showcase div ul#sites li a {
    border: 1px solid #9CF;
    color: #69C;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 5px;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.showcase div ul#sites li a:hover {
    border: 1px solid #69C;
}
.showcase div ul#details {
    line-height: 160%;
}
/* footer */
#footer {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #BBB;
    clear: both;
}
#footer h2 {
    color: #EEE;
}
#footer p {
    color: #BBB;
}
/* contact */
#footer-top {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
    line-height: 160%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 30px 0;
    width: 960px; /* ie6 hack */
}
#footer-top div {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#contact {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 40px 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#contact form {
    margin: 20px 0 0;
}

#sendmail label {
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
#sendmail label.error{
    color: #FF4444;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
#sendmail label {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: top;
    cursor: hand;
}
#name, #email, #message {
    border: 0;
    background-color: #444;
    font-family: Arial, "MS Trebuchet", sans-serif;
    color: #BBB;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 6px;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    width: 380px;
}
#name:focus, #email:focus, #message:focus {
    background-color: #555;
}
#message {
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
#button {
    background-color: #69C;
    border-color: #69C;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial, "MS Trebuchet", sans-serif;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 100px
}
#button:hover {
    background-color: #49C;
    border-color: #49C;
}
/*\*//*/ form.contact legend { display: inline-block; } /* IE Mac legend fix */
#info {
    float: right;
    width: 303px;
    margin: 0 0 0 40px;
}
#tools {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 0 40px;
    width: 83px;
}
/* about */
#footer-bottom {
    font-size: 10px;
    margin: 15px auto;
}
```

EDIT: ...or do you know any css optimizer which nest css selector and properties together?

Comment: Good question. I was thinking yesterday that a tool that consolidates CSS would be absolutely amazing. Maybe something that creates http://www.dotlesscss.com/ files from legacy CSS? :D

Comment: I don't think that a specific css file like that can be noted alot shorter then it is now. It looks like there was a valid reason for splitting up this many css classes.

Answer (score 3):

You can delete `/*\*//*/ form.contact legend { display: inline-block; } /* IE Mac legend fix */` — even Microsoft doesn’t support Mac IE any more.

Answer (score 2):

First of all remove all css hacks and place them in other, browser specific, files, which you'll be including via [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

Comment: Bad point there. You shouldn't use separate stylesheets to include hacks.

Comment: Why should you load hacks which target IE on all other browsers?

Answer (score 2):

[Cleancss.com](http://www.cleancss.com/) seems to do the trick. You can choose between a bunch of different options. Check it out and see if it's something that could work for you!

Comment: was gonna suggest it, though you beat me to it :P

Answer (score 1):

if you have margin: 0 0 20px 0; - you can remove the last 0 as this is the left margin which is the same as the right.

There are a few online tools that can optimize css if you google for them(e.g. http://flumpcakes.co.uk/css/optimiser/). There is a fine line between optimisation and maintainability though. If you remove all the comments etc that will make the file smaller but less maintainable. Again you can remove all the line breaks to make a smaller file but not sure that is better.

I would probably not use a reset.

To me you CSS seems pretty compact already.

Comment: “I would probably not use a reset.” — bit risky removing a reset from an existing stylesheet though. Difficult to tell what’s relied on, and what’s not.

Comment: yep - but I wouldn't have put it in to start with/

Answer (score 0):

You've got 5kb of [cacheable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036941/setup-expires-headers-php-apache), [gzippable](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html) CSS there, which would be even less if you [stripped comments and whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65491/what-is-the-best-method-to-reduce-the-size-of-my-javascript-and-css-files/65505#65505). Trying to optimise any further than that I don't think is worth more than about 3 seconds of your time, really.

Answer (score 0):

On #button

```
border-color: #69C; 
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
```

can be written more concisely as

```
border:1px solid #69c;
```

Answer (score 0):

On https://purifycss.online/ you just need:

to enter the URL of the website,

hit "Clean up CSS" button, and:

you'll be able to download to purified CSS.

It worked for me like a charm.