# Enums with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, enums

```
$("#bc [id$=_dropdownID]").change(function() {
    if (this.value == '2' || this.value == '3') {
        $("#bc .pnl").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#bc .pnl").hide();
    }
```

I have the following code in jQuery. Is there any way I can replace the hard coded constants 2 and 3 in the above code with a c# enum? Does jQuery support enums and if so how can this be achieved?
Any suggestions welcome....

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287903/enums-in-javascript for lots of discussion.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You would have to duplicate the enum in JavaScript like so:

```
var myEnum = {
         OneValue: 2,
         AnotherValue: 3
};
```

then you can use it like this:

```
this.value === myEnum.OneValue || this.value === myEnum.AnotherValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Im using this way:
If you got a  enum anywhere in your c# project like :

```
   public enum MyEnum
     {
        One = 1,
        Two= 2
     }
```

(Supposing you wanna use it your entire project)
In your  Shared.Layout.cshtml file , at first line put its reference like bellow

```
@using MyProject.NameSpace.MyEnum
```

Inside Layout.cshml, at  section put something like bellow

```
<script>
  const myEnum = { 
    One : @Convert.ToInt16(MyProject.NameSpace.MyEnum.One),
    Two : @Convert.ToInt16(MyProject.NameSpace.MyEnum.Two)
  }
</script>
```

In other places just compare something like

```
<script>
if(AnyValue == myEnum.One){
console.log(myEnum.One)
}
</script>
```