# JavaScript ES6 `const a = {}` is mutable. Why?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Using JavaScript ES6, I am surprised that doing:

```
const a = {};
a.foo = 'bar';
a.foo = 'car';
```

Is valid. Why is this? I would have assumed `const` would mean you cannot change the `a` empty object and apply new properties. Even further, I would also have assumed you cannot change the value of a property of `a` once it is set.

Comment: I would say that one 'good' thing I do like about Java is that its constant variables are a lot clearer to beginners. Java uses `final` (which might correctly imply that this is the final value the variable will hold) instead of `const` (which might falsely imply that the value of this variable are constant and cannot be changed). Write `const`, but imagine it says `final` instead when declaring constant javascript variables.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Only the variable assignment is constant. Any objects or arrays referenced stay mutable.

```
const a = {one: 1};
a.three = 3; // this is ok.
a = {two: 2}; // this doesn't work.
```

What you *can* do is use `Object.freeze`:

```
const a = {one: 1};
Object.freeze(a);
a.three = 3; // silently fails.
// a is still {one: 1} here.
```

Answer (score 7):

No, `const a` means you cannot change the value of the variable `a`. Its value is always the same object; changing properties of an object doesn't make it into a different object.

Using an analogy, I am the same `Person` whether `amadan.jacket = null` or `amadan.jacket = "Heavy Winter Jacket"`. `amadan` is constant.

To make the properties immutable, you would either have to make the properties explicitly readonly by `writable: false`, or use `Object.freeze` or `Object.seal` ([differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21402108/difference-between-freeze-and-seal-in-javascript)) to make the entire object immutable.