# ES6 const for creating object prototypes in JavaScript; is this a pattern?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I often see `const` being used to create a base object.

1. Is this a pattern?
2. If yes, what are the advantages?

[Example from here](https://youtu.be/riDVvXZ_Kb4?t=1m):

```
const food = {
    init: function(type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}

const waffle = Object.create(food);
waffle.init('waffle');
console.log(waffle.type);
```

Comment: #1 Depends on your definition of "pattern". #2 Declaring variables with *const* just means the value can't be reassigned. No particular non–obvious advantages other than makes compiling from other languages into ECMAScript easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`const` declares a readonly reference. You cannot change the value if declared with `const`. See documantation from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const):

> The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It
>   does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable
>   identifier cannot be reassigned.

For example:

```
const x = {a:2};//declaration. 
x={b:3};//This statement throws an exception
x.c=4;//This is ok!
```

So, `const` provides these:

1. The initial defined object cannot be reassigned.(readonly)
2. The properties of the initial object can be reassigned.
3. New properties can be added to the initial object.

**These are perfectly suitable for class definitions!**

On the other hand, there are two alternatives to declare a value: `var` and `let`. Both cannot provide read-only referencing. Also `var` doesn't provide a block-scope declaration. Of course you can use either `var` or `let`. This is your choice and your usage.

Also in ES6, you can define classes like that (resource from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)):

```
class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}
```

And [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) translates it like this (by using `var`):

```
function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

var Polygon = function Polygon(height, width) {
  _classCallCheck(this, Polygon);

  this.height = height;
  this.width = width;
};
```

Comment: To be a bit more precise: `const` generates an immutable *binding*, i.e. you cannot reassign a different value. The *value* of the binding is still mutable and can be changed in any way possible.

Comment: Btw, where did the first example come from? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34983693/javascript-es6-const-a-is-mutable-why uses the same one...

Comment: That example is totally my interpretation of [MDN link provided by me](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

Comment: Ha, it's too early in the morning for me, I can't even compare code properly :P

Comment: @ykaragol thanks for your elaborate answer. I read MDN doc before I post my question. It is very clear how `const` works. My question was about its use in that specific setting.