# JavaScript idiom for limiting a string to a number of discrete values

Tags: javascript, enumeration

In C# I might use an enumeration.

In JavaScript, how can I limit a value to a set of discrete values idiomatically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287903/enums-in-javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We sometimes define a variable in a JS class 'Enumerations' along these lines:

```
var Sex = {
    Male: 1,
    Female: 2
};
```

And then reference it just like a C# enumeration.

Comment: Thanks. You are capitalizing the object name here because it refers to a constructor function (Object)?

Comment: Not particularly, just a hark back to C# and the way we'd use upper case in there.

Answer (score 1):

There is no enumeration type in JavaScript.
You could, however, wrap an object with a getter and setter method around it like

```
var value = (function() {
   var val;
   return {
      'setVal': function( v ) {
                   if ( v in [ listOfEnums ] ) {
                       val = v;
                   } else {
                       throw 'value is not in enumeration';
                   }
                },
      'getVal': function() { return val; }
   };
 })();
```

Comment: thanks +1, but if you do something stupid and call it incorrectly `value.setVal = 'debug Hell'` you end up replacing the function with the string and that's where you are! ...Working now.

Comment: Better starting the above with `const value = (function...` I think.

Comment: `const` wouldnt help you with that. You would need to use something like [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) if you want to account for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can't.

Strong typing doesn't exist in JavaScript, so it's not possible to confine your input parameters to a specific type or set of values.