# Enum usage in javascript

Tags: javascript

i was searching Enum usage in javascript. i found one stackoverflow link 
[Enums in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287903/enums-in-javascript) it is good start.

this link show one good use like

```
var SIZE = {
SMALL : {value: 0, name: "Small", code: "S"}, 
MEDIUM: {value: 1, name: "Medium", code: "M"}, 
LARGE : {value: 2, name: "Large", code: "L"}
};

var currentSize = SIZE.MEDIUM;
if (currentSize == SIZE.MEDIUM) {
// this alerts: "1: Medium"
alert(currentSize.value + ": " + currentSize.name);
}
```

my requirement was bit different and that why i change the above code like

```
var MSg = {
        Country= {
                    GBR: {name_req:"Name Required",email_req:"Email Required"},
                    FRA: {name_req:"FRA Name Required",email_req:"FRA Email Required"}
                 }

    };

but it is giving error. so please guide me how to write the above code without error. also tell me the enum code will work in all the browser? thanks.
```

### **For my own future references**

```
var dialog =
    {
        MainContainer:
        {
            Country:
            {
                GBR:
                    {
                        height: 365, width: 257
                    },
                FRA:
                    {
                        height: 375, width: 310
                    }

            }
        },
        SubContainer:
        {
            Country:
            {
                GBR:
                    {
                        height: 0, width: 257
                    },
                FRA:
                    {
                        height: 0, width: 300
                    }
            }
        }
    };

    var Validation =
    {
        Msg:
        {
            Country:
            {
                GBR:
                    {
                        Name: "Name Required",
                        Subject: "Subject Required",
                        Email: "Email Required",
                        Invalid_Email: "Invalid Email Address",
                        Feedback: "Feedback details Required",
                        Success: "Feedback send successfully",
                        Fail: "Feedback send fail"
                    },
                USA:
                    {
                        Name: "Name Required",
                        Subject: "Subject Required",
                        Email: "Email Required",
                        Invalid_Email: "Invalid Email Address",
                        Feedback: "Feedback details Required",
                        Success: "Feedback send successfully",
                        Fail: "Feedback send fail"
                    }
            }
        }
    };
```

### **assignment or set country**

```
 var feedCookie = getCookie('SetCountry');
 feedCookie = (feedCookie == '' ? 'GBR' : feedCookie);
 var dialog_Main = dialog.MainContainer.Country[feedCookie];
 var dialog_Sub = dialog.SubContainer.Country[feedCookie];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do:

```
var MSg = {
    Country : {
                GBR: {name_req:"Name Required",email_req:"Email Required"},
                FRA: {name_req:"FRA Name Required",email_req:"FRA Email Required"}
             }

};
```

Now, `var c =MSg.Country.GBR` will give you `c = {name_req:"Name Required",email_req:"Email Required"}`

Comment: Don't use this syntax, it won't survive (de)serialization. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 5):

You don't use `=` inside an object definition.  You use `:` to define a new property.
So change `Country = {` to `Country: {` like this:

```
var MSg = {
    Country: {
                GBR: {name_req:"Name Required",email_req:"Email Required"},
                FRA: {name_req:"FRA Name Required",email_req:"FRA Email Required"}
             }

};
```

Answer (score 1):

The original answer from the question referenced by the OP, suggesting this syntax:

```
var SIZE = {
    SMALL : {value: 0, name: "Small", code: "S"}, 
    MEDIUM: {value: 1, name: "Medium", code: "M"}, 
    LARGE : {value: 2, name: "Large", code: "L"}
};
```

was mine. However in the meanwhile I learned more and I now recommend *against* this appoach. **Don't use this syntax!** This approach has serious issues when the enum needs to be serialized (`JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` etc).

**Use this syntax instead:**

```
var SIZE = {
    SMALL: 0,
    MEDIUM: 1,
    LARGE: 2,

    properties: {
        0: {value: 0, name: "Small", code: "S"},
        1: {value: 1, name: "Medium", code: "M"}, 
        2: {value: 2, name: "Large", code: "L"}
    }
};
```

A bit more verbose, yes. And accessing the properties of the enum values is also a little less intuitive:

```
var size = SIZE.SMALL;
var code = SIZE.properties[size].code;
```

However, this way your enum values will survive (de)serialization. And in today's web with it's Ajax requests, REST API's and JSON responses, that's so important that it's a sacrifice we should make.

Read my blog post about this topic for more details: 
[Enums in Javascript - Stijn de Witt's Blog](https://stijndewitt.wordpress.com/2014/01/26/enums-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
var MSg = {
        Country= {
                    GBR: {name_req:"Name Required",email_req:"Email Required"},
                    FRA: {name_req:"FRA Name Required",email_req:"FRA Email Required"}
                 }

    };
```

Oughtta be this:

```
var MSg = {
        Country: { // <- RIGHT HERE
                    GBR: {name_req:"Name Required",email_req:"Email Required"},
                    FRA: {name_req:"FRA Name Required",email_req:"FRA Email Required"}
                 }

    };
```