# How create enum in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need create named constant.

for example:

```
NAME_FIELD: {
            CAR : "car", 
            COLOR: "color"}
```

using:

```
var temp = NAME_FIELD.CAR // valid
var temp2 = NAME_FIELD.CAR2 // throw exception
```

most of all I need to make this enum caused error if the key is not valid

Comment: There are no enums in javascript

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287903/enums-in-javascript
I think it is duplicate

Answer (score 1):

> most of all I need to make this enum caused error if the key is not valid

Unfortunately, you can't. The way you're doing pseudo-enums is the usual way, which is to create properties on an object, but you can't get the JavaScript engine to throw an error if you try to retrieve a property from the object that doesn't exist. Instead, the engine will return `undefined`.

You could do this by using a function, which obviously has utility issues.

Alternately (and I really don't like this idea), you could do something like this:

```
var NAME_FIELD$CAR = "car";
var NAME_FIELD$COLOR = "color";
```

Since you would access those as free identifiers, trying to read a value that didn't exist:

```
var temp2 = NAME_FIELD$CAR2;
```

...fails with a `ReferenceError`. (This is true even in non-strict mode code; the [*Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) only applies to *writing* to a free identifier, not reading from one.)

Answer (score 0):

Now that custom setters and getters in plain javascript objects are deprecated, a solution could be to define a class for your object and a `set` function :

```
NAME_FIELD= {
     CAR : "CAR", 
     COLOR: "COLOR"
};

function MyClass(){
}
MyClass.prototype.setProp = function (val) {
  if (!(val in NAME_FIELD)) throw {noGood:val};
  this.prop = val;
}
var obj = new MyClass();

obj.setProp(NAME_FIELD.CAR); // no exception
obj.setProp('bip'); // throws an exception
```

But as enums aren't a native construct, I'm not sure I would use such a thing. This smells too much as *"trying to force a java feature in javascript"*. You probably don't need this.

Comment: Why setter, why not getter?

Comment: I mean the OP wants to throw exception if he *gets* the invalid property.