# Converting enums to array of values (Putting all JSON values in an array)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, enums

I use this method [Enums in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287903/enums-in-javascript) to create enums in our code..

So

```
var types = {
  "WHITE" : 0,
  "BLACK" : 1
}
```

Now the issue is when I want create validations anywhere, I have to do this;

```
model.validate("typesColumn", [ types.WHITE, types.BLACK ]);
```

Now is there a way I can just simple convert the values in types to an array so that I don't have to list all of the values of the enum?

```
model.validate("typesColumn", types.ValuesInArray]);
```

**EDIT**: I created a very simple enum library to generate simple enums `npm --save-dev install simple-enum` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-enum)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would convert the map into an array and store it as `types.all`.
You can create a method that does it automatically:

```
function makeEnum(enumObject){
   var all = [];
   for(var key in enumObject){
      all.push(enumObject[key]);
   }
   enumObject.all = all;
}
```

Comment: I think this is the nicest solution.. I can call makeEnum when declaring enums then just be able to call .all

Comment: Does this even do what is required? Surely after this `all` would be and array of property names? like `['WHITE', 'BLACK']` rather than an array of values (which the OP has requested). Also, `enum` is a reserved word! Why was this accepted?...

Comment: I guess the OP took the idea without looking into the exact implementation that is indeed incorrect. I will correct it for other users, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 116):

**Simple solution (ES6)**

You can use `Object.values` like this:

```
var valueArray = Object.values(types);
```

**[Online demo (fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/o6t2udh1/)**

Comment: If the enum is a string, (ex. enum { "Hello", "Goodbye" } then `Object.keys(enum)` works.

Answer (score 10):

```
var types = {
  "WHITE" : 0,
  "BLACK" : 1
}
var typeArray = Object.keys(types).map(function(type) {
    return types[type];
});
//typeArray [0,1]

model.validate("typesColumn", typeArray);
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dJBbY/)

Comment: +1 for `Object.keys`. Modern JavaScript code for modern environments like node.js!

Comment: +1, but I'd rather refactor `keys` + `map` to a general function `values(obj)` and then simply `validate("typesColumn", values(types))`.

Answer (score 2):

You could convert it to an array, or you can just iterate the properties of the object (which is how you would create the array anyway):

```
for(var i in types){
    var type = types[i];
    //in the first iteration: i = "WHITE", type = 0
    //in the second iteration: i = "BLACK", type = 1
}
```

---

Just for completeness, you can create the array with that method as follows:

```
var arr = [];
for(var i in types){
    var type = types[i];
    arr.push(type);
}
//arr = [0, 1]
```

---

to make this reusable you could create a helper function:

```
function ObjectToValueArray(obj){
    var arr = [];
    for(var i in obj){
        var v = obj[i];
        arr.push(v);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Which can be called like so:

```
model.validate("typesColumn", ObjectToValueArray(types));
```

Comment: I know that I can convert these but since these are used in various places, I'm looking for a one line solution. Something very simple that supports this functionality

Comment: Create a helper function and re-use that

Answer (score 1):

Juice up (or wrap) `.validate` such that it will accept `types` as meaning all members?

```
var types = {
  "WHITE" : 0,
  "BLACK" : 1,
  "RED"   : 200
}

validate("foo", types.WHITE); // 0
validate("foo", [types.WHITE, types.BLACK]); // 0,1 
validate("foo", types); // 0,1,200

function validate(foo, values) { 
    var arr = [];
    switch (typeof values) {
        case "number":
            arr.push(values);
            break;
        case "object":
            if (values instanceof Array) 
                arr = values;
            else {
                for (var k in values)
                    arr.push(values[k]);
            }
            break;
    }
    alert(arr);
}
```