# Get array of string literal type values

Tags: typescript

I need to get a full list of all possible values for a string literal.

```
type YesNo = "Yes" | "No";
let arrayOfYesNo : Array<string> = someMagicFunction(YesNo); //["Yes", "No"]
```

Is there any way of achiving this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Typescript 2.4 is [finally released](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2017/06/27/announcing-typescript-2-4/). With the support of string enums I no longer have to use string literals and because typescript enums are compiled to javascript I can access them at runtime (same approach as for [number enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150659/converting-enums-to-array-of-values-putting-all-json-values-in-an-array)).

Comment: There is no bidirectional mapping for string enums however

Answer (score 22):

Enumeration may help you here:

```
enum YesNo {
    YES,
    NO
}

interface EnumObject {
    [enumValue: number]: string;
}

function getEnumValues(e: EnumObject): string[] {
    return Object.keys(e).map((i) => e[i]);
}

getEnumValues(YesNo); // ['YES', 'NO']
```

`type` declaration doesn't create any symbol that you could use in runtime, it only creates an alias in type system. So there's no way you can use it as a function argument.

If you need to have string values for `YesNo` type, you can use a trick (since string values of enums aren't part of TS [yet](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/15486)):

```
const YesNoEnum = {
   Yes: 'Yes',
   No: 'No'
};

function thatAcceptsYesNoValue(vale: keyof typeof YesNoEnum): void {}
```

Then you can use `getEnumValues(YesNoEnum)` to get possible values for `YesNoEnum`, i.e. ['Yes', 'No']. It's a bit ugly, but that'd work.

To be honest, I would've gone with just a static variable like this:

```
type YesNo = 'yes' | 'no';
const YES_NO_VALUES: YesNo[] = ['yes', 'no'];
```

Comment: When I try @KirillDmitrenko's suggestion. My array allows non literal values as well. For example `const YES_NO_VALUES: YesNo[] = [ 'yes', 'no', 'maybe'];`

Comment: Shouldn't the getEnumValues function be: ```function getEnumValues(e: EnumObject): string[] {
  return Object.keys(e).map((_, idx: number): string => e[idx]);
}```