# Ways to get string literal type of array values without enum overhead

Tags: typescript

In my project I need a number of string literal types and arrays of allowed values for variuos tasks like typeguards.

This is what we have:

```
type Animal = 'cat' | 'dog' | 'rabbit' | 'snake'
const animals: Animal[] = ['cat', 'dog', 'rabbit', 'snake']
```

It works, but it requires to list keys several times in source code.

Another way is to use enums as suggested in [Get array of string literal type values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44154009) but it creates overhead in runtime as compiled code for enum is bigger then array.

I found another way to do it that have no runtime overhead, but I'm not sure if it will work in the future, as it may be a bug.

```
const notWidened = <T extends string>(val: T[]) => val

const animals = notWidened(['cat', 'dog', 'rabbit', 'snake'])
type Animal = typeof animals[0]
```

So the question is if it's safe to use this snippet or it is going to break in the future. Is there a better way to get both literal string type and array without duplication.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480644/typescript-string-union-to-string-array) may be related... see if my updated [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45486495/2887218) helps you.

Comment: But your method looks fine to me also.

Comment: At least, I can replace `typeof animals[0]` with `typeof animals[number]`, which looks a lot better!

Comment: you know in 2.4 you can have string enums? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't find a good piece of documentation for this at the moment, but your `notWidened()` function works just fine and is not a bug.  TypeScript will infer string literals for generic type variables if you constrain the type parameter to `string` or a subtype of `string`.  So `<T extends keyof U>`, `<T extends string>`, `<T extends 'a'|'b'>`, etc. will infer string literals for `T`.  (You can also infer `number` or `boolean` literals if you constrain `T` similarly).

So your code is just fine as far as I can see; the only thing I might do differently is

```
type Animal = (typeof animals)[number]
```

instead of

```
type Animal = typeof animals[0]
```

since the `0`th element of `animals` is actually `'cat'`, even though you've told TypeScript it is `'cat'|'dog'|...`.  Yours is fine, though.

As I commented above, if you want TypeScript to consider `animals` to be a tuple where `animals[0]` is of type `'cat'`, and `animals[1]` is of type `'dog'`, etc., you can use something like the function `tuple()` <strike>in [tuple.ts](https://gist.github.com/jcalz/381562d282ebaa9b41217d1b31e2c211)</strike>  (**UPDATE July 2018**, starting in TypeScript 3.0 the compiler will be able to [infer tuple types automatically](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897), so the function can be more succinct):

```
export type Lit = string | number | boolean | undefined | null | void | {};
export const tuple = <T extends Lit[]>(...args: T) => args;

const animals = tuple('cat', 'dog', 'rabbit', 'snake');
type Animal = (typeof animals)[number];  // union type
```

which might come in handy for you.

---

TL;DR:  your code is fine.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use a **const** enum string, this has none runtime overhead. It compiles the values into the code ([Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20enum%20Animals%20%7B%0D%0A%20Cat%20%3D%20'cat'%2C%0D%0A%20Dog%20%3D%20'dog'%2C%0D%0A%20Rabbit%20%3D%20'rabbit'%2C%0D%0A%20Snake%20%3D%20'snake'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aalert(Animals.Cat))):

```
const enum Animals {
  Cat = 'cat',
  Dog = 'dog',
  Rabbit = 'rabbit',
  Snake = 'snake'
}

alert(Animals.Cat)

// Generated JavaScript code: 
// alert("cat" /* Cat */);
```