# How do I runtime-safeguard my assert from string to type literal?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, type-assertion

I am coding a crude abstract syntax tree based on user input. In my AST type, I want to have type literals for valid operators. How do I convert the user input (strings) to string type literals in a safe manner? Consider the snippet below.

```
type operator = '==' | '!=';

function isOperator(raw: string): raw is operator {
    return ['==', '!='].indexOf(raw) !== -1
}

const parseOperator = (raw: string) => {
    if (isOperator(raw)) {
        return raw
    } else {
        throw new Error('Invalid input')
    }
}

const indata: string[] = ['!=', '!=', '==','a']
const data: operator[] = indata.map(parseOperator)
```

In the code, I have duplicated the valid operators (once in the type definition, and later in the parsing logic). That seems to be a bad way to structure code, since updating the operator type means I have to update hard coded arrays in other places.

What is the idiosyncratic typescript way to do this assertion?

ps. I realize this question: [Ways to get string literal type of array values without enum overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46176165/ways-to-get-string-literal-type-of-array-values-without-enum-overhead) is realated. The answerthere seems kind-of-hackish to me though. If that is the best poossible solution - please explain why it is a good coding style.