# What does typeof tuple with index type signature represents?

Tags: typescript

I've following Typescript code and I can't really make sense of last line of code

```
const tuple = <T extends string[]>(...args: T) => args;
const ButtonTypes = tuple('default', 'primary', 'ghost', 'dashed', 'danger', 'link');
export type ButtonType = (typeof ButtonTypes)[number];
```

This is the line I'm talking to be more explicit.

```
(typeof ButtonTypes)[number]
```

**Update**:

This follows directly from [Ways to get string literal type of array values without enum overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46176165/ways-to-get-string-literal-type-of-array-values-without-enum-overhead)

Comment: `typeof ButtonTypes` resolves to a type of the variable (array of strings). `[number]` means effectively: "select every type from the array".

Comment: `typeof ButtonTypes` this is fine as it's javascript. What would be "[number] means effectively: "select every type from the array""

Comment: Not exactly - `typeof ButtonTypes` means something different when Typescript knows it's trying to evaluate a *type* compared to when it's trying to evaluate an *expression* (like in standard JS). Here, it's trying to evaluate a type, so `typeof ButtonTypes` does *not* turn into `'object'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tuple` is a function that takes arguments, and returns an array of all arguments. For example, `tuple('foo', 'bar')` will evaluate to `['foo', 'bar']`.

With

```
const ButtonTypes = tuple('default', 'primary', 'ghost', 'dashed', 'danger', 'link');
```

you'll get an array of all those strings:

```
const ButtonTypes = ['default', 'primary', 'ghost', 'dashed', 'danger', 'link'];
```

Then, with `(typeof foo)[number]`, you'll retrieve all properties on the variable `foo` which can be accessed with a numeric index. So, it's just like doing the following:

```
export type ButtonType = "default" | "primary" | "ghost" | "dashed" | "danger" | "link";
```

only less repetitive.

Comment: I'm not sure if I fathom this completely. `(typeof foo)[number]` compiles down to `array[number] ` ? Is that correct?  If so, don't we normally do `string []` to specify . the array with a type

Comment: No, because Typescript is trying to evaluate a *type* here, rather than a normal Javascript expression. (and the `typeof` an array is `object`, not `array`)

Comment: How am I getting an array of all strings assigned to `ButtonTypes` as the function is just returning `args` ?

Comment: You called `tuple` with a bunch of arguments and assigned the result to `ButtonTypes`, and Typescript is smart enough to understand that `ButtonTypes` is now an array composed of those arguments. So, if you just take the `typeof` that array in a type context, you'll get the type of the array, and the `[number]` will turn that into a union type of all arguments initially passed to `tuple`.

Comment: By `Typescript is smart` enough you mean `<T extends string[]>` will cast args into string array and thus return the array. Correct?

Comment: That's only for getting the typings correct - if you're wondering about how the array is gotten out of it, `(...args` uses rest parameter syntax to gather all parameters into an array, just like in standard Javascript, so, eg, Typescript will know (at compile time) that `tuple('foo', 'bar')` will result in `['foo', 'bar']`

Comment: Yes. Missed that. But let me ask me this which will make clear hopefully. What if I don't specify an index signature ? That is, what if I do `(typeof ButtonTypes)[]` instead of `(typeof ButtonTypes)[number]`?

Comment: Then you would be specifying a type which is an *array* of `ButtonTypes`, eg `const manyButtonTypes: ButtonType = [ButtonTypes, ButtonTypes];` (which isn't what you want, of course)

Comment: For some reason it's seeming strange due to the fact that we don't access objects with number index normally in Javascript. And since the value of `ButtonType ` is `object[number]` it is just not clear what's going on here. Had it been `array[number]` would still have something to reason about the index signature. That I'm restricting the access of the array to only number indexes which is the default anyway

Comment: We do often access arrays with numeric indicies - in fact, you rarely see anything else. `arr[3]`. It's less common with objects, but we're dealing with an array here

Comment: M saying exactly the same. That we are dealing with object here and we do often deal with arrays that way

Comment: Yeah, it's somewhat confusing, because the `[]` syntax is overloaded (1: Javascript property accessor 2: Typescript index signature 3. Typescript array type notation)

Comment: For example I'm going to use this type as 

`export interface IBaseButtonProps {
type?: ButtonType; 
...}
`and then use this as `<Button type='primary' />`. Basically I'm specifiying a string. How does `ButtonType` resolves  this? Let me start that process of drilling down. ButtonType according to our discussion is `object[number]`. My processing is blocked here. See what I'm trying to understand and how to map.

Comment: `ButtonType` is just `"default" | "primary" | "ghost" | "dashed" | "danger" | "link"`, so the `{ type?: ButtonType; ...}` means that a `type` property, if it exists, needs to be one of those strings.

Comment: Anyway, I'll try thinking that way and sticking to it. I get it on surface for sure. Still confused about index type signature as @Foydor mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Line `(typeof ButtonTypes)[number]` combined of following parts:

1. `typeof ButtonTypes` extract type of constant `ButtonTypes`. Type of `ButtonTypes` is [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple).
2. Square braces `[]` after type means [indexed access operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types). It extracts type of property from object type (it's all about types). In this case, object type is `typeof ButtonTypes` which is tuple.
3. In square braces there is `number` which gets [type of index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-string-index-signatures). As tuple is essentially array, it has number index signature. And as tuple consists of elements of different types, `(typeof ButtonTypes)[number]` resolved to [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) `"default" | "primary" | "ghost" | "dashed" | "danger" | "link"`

And several examples to understand all this staff :-)

This is type

```
interface I1 {
    prop1: string;
    func2: (a: string) => void;
}
```

This is constant of type `I1`

```
const c1: I1 = {/*...*/}
```

`typeof c1` is `I1`.

Indexed access operator for `I1` will get types of properties. For example

```
type s = I1['prop1']; // Type s is string
type f = I1['func2']; // Type f is function
```

And to get type of index signature, we should have type with index signature. So create one

```
interface I2 {
    [key: string]: string;
}
```

Now

```
type s1 = I2[string]; // type of s1 is string
let str: s1 = "some string"; // This is allowed, as type of s1 is string
```

Arrays and tuples has index signature of type `number` so

```
let a = [1, 2, 3];
type ta = (typeof a)[number];  // type ta is number
```

Comment: `type ta = (typeof a)[number];  // type ta is number`. Are you sure?

Comment: Yes, as `a` is array. And array is essentially object with number index signature. Type of array elements is `number`, so `(typeof a)[number]` is `number`