# How to define a list of choices using an array with React Typescript Interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Can someone help me define a type that could be any one of items in an array please? Say I have a long list of choices for the type, instead of listing each one I want to be able to use an array to define the list of choices. For example, instead of this:

```js
interface IProps {
  buttonType: "string1" | "string2" | "string3" ...;
  ...
}
```

I want something like this:

```js
const buttonTypes = ["string1", "string2", "string3", ...];

interface IProps {
  buttonType: typeof buttonTypes; <- this is the issue, the type here becomes string[]
  ...
}
```

I'm a typescript newb so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Declare the array `as const` so it doesn't get widened to `string[]`, then use `[number]` to turn the tuple type into a union

Comment: Thanks! Your comment set me on the right path and lead me to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46176165/ways-to-get-string-literal-type-of-array-values-without-enum-overhead