# JavaScript, defining unmodifiable Enumerations

Tags: javascript, enums, unmodifiable

So, I was inspired by this question ( [Enums in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287903/enums-in-javascript/) ) to get to work on a library insert for JavaScript to enable unmodifiable Enumerations. I have a decently working method defined already, but I'd like to flesh it out more.

This concept makes use of `Object.defineProperty` (Documentation: [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty))

My current definition allows for :

```
var obj1 = {}, obj2 = {}, obj3 = {};
// Straight declaration (normal)
obj1.Enum('RED','BLUE','GREEN');
obj1.RED    // == 0
obj1.BLUE   // == 1
obj1.GREEN  // == 2
// Buffer (padding) usage
obj2.Enum('RED','BLUE',null,undefined,'','GREEN');
obj2.RED    // == 0
obj2.BLUE   // == 1
obj2.GREEN  // == 5
// Direct offset and case-correction
obj3.Enum('RED','BLUE',10,'gReEn','burnt orange');
obj3.RED           // == 0
obj3.BLUE          // == 1
obj3.GREEN         // == 11
obj3.BURNT_ORANGE  // == 12
```

What I have so far:

```
var odp=Object.defineProperty;
odp(Object.prototype,'Enum', {
    value: function() {
        var ignore=[undefined,null,''], n=0, args=arguments;
        for(var i in args) {
            if(ignore.indexOf(args[i])<0) {
                if( typeof args[i]=="number") {
                    n=parseInt(args[i]);
                } else {
                    try {
                        odp(this,String(args[i]).toUpperCase().replace(" ","_"), {
                            value:parseInt(n),enumerable:true
                        });
                    } catch(e) {
                        console.warn(e.message);
                        n--;
                    }
                }
            }
            n++;
        }
        return this;
    }
});
```

2 things I'd like to add to this are:

1. Older browser support: So, redefining `Object.defineProperty` where it's not defined. (I don't currently have access to the older browsers to test possible re-definitions)
2. Any considerations I may have missed it the Enum definition.

jsFiddle :

- Version 4: http://jsfiddle.net/rqYgt/4/
- Version 5: http://jsfiddle.net/rqYgt/5/

**Note:** The reason I have `odp=Object.defineProperty` and `args=arguments` is that I run my JavaScript through a closure compiler before inserting it into my pages, doing this assists with compression. (for those that may be wondering)

Comment: How are these "type safe"?

Comment: Object.defineProperty defaults to non-writable values.

Comment: @Duncan *"Object.defineProperty defaults to non-writable values"* Okay, so that has nothing whatsoever to do with type safety. It has to do with not letting the enum get changed, yeah, but...

Comment: check the jsFiddle... they can't be rewritten

Comment: Ahh yes... bit of confusion on terminology there... edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Older browser support: So, redefining `Object.defineProperty` where it's not defined.

You can't do that with your current approach, because your current approach extends `Object.prototype`. Extending `Object.prototype` should *very, very rarely* be done if you have ES5 support, but it **must never be done** without it, because without `Object.defineProperty`, you have no way to create a non-enumerable property. Adding enumerable properties to `Object.property` will break all of your `for-in` loops.

There's no reason for `Enum` to be on the prototype anyway, though, just put it on `Object` (or your own library object) and pass the object to be enum-ified into it.

> Any considerations I may have missed it the Enum definition.

It seems to me that this offers little on top of:

```
var obj = Object.freeze({
    "RED":   0,
    "GREEN": 1,
    "BLUE":  2
});
```

You might wrap that up into a function that will work, without freezing the object, in pre-ES5 environments, e.g.:

```
function createEnum(spec) {
    if (Object.freeze) {
        spec = Object.freeze(spec);
    }
    return spec;
}
```

You can enhance that, of course, if you want the automatic values, e.g:

```
function createEnum(spec) {
    var obj = {}, n;
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(spec) === "[object Array]") { // No isArray pre ES5
        for (n = 0; n < spec.length; ++n) {
            if (spec[n] != null) { // checks for null or undefined
                obj[spec[n]] = n;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        for (n in spec) {
            if (spec.hasOwnProperty(n)) {
                obj[n] = spec[n];
            }
        }
    }
    if (Object.freeze) {
        obj = Object.freeze(obj);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

You could put that on `Object` (**not** `Object.prototype`), if you liked.

---

Below you've said that you don't want to use `freeze` because it makes the object non-extensible. Fair enough, wanting to add further enum values later. The above is easily adapted to doing that, using `Object.defineProperty` if present and falling back on just assigning the property if not.

Comment: Object.freeze freezes the object, what I'm doing is not freezing the object, but making unalterable properties... you can still change other properties of the same object... So, you can create an object with Enum members.

Comment: @Duncan: Comingling enum members and non-enum members in the same object sounds like a questionable design choice. But yes, `freeze` would prevent you adding new enum values to the object later.

Comment: Also, the Enum method won't show in the for-each loop on an object as it's not part of the object enumerables (not listed in the for-each loop)... each Enumator defined on an object will show in that object's for-each loop, but any attempt at assignment on the individual property fails silently, so no harm, no foul.