# How to shorten switch case block converting a number to a month name?

Tags: javascript, date, switch-statement, date-format

Is there a way to write this on fewer lines, but still easily readable?

```
var month = '';

switch(mm) {
    case '1':
        month = 'January';
        break;
    case '2':
        month = 'February';
        break;
    case '3':
        month = 'March';
        break;
    case '4':
        month = 'April';
        break;
    case '5':
        month = 'May';
        break;
    case '6':
        month = 'June';
        break;
    case '7':
        month = 'July';
        break;
    case '8':
        month = 'August';
        break;
    case '9':
        month = 'September';
        break;
    case '10':
        month = 'October';
        break;
    case '11':
        month = 'November';
        break;
    case '12':
        month = 'December';
        break;
}
```

Comment: IMHO [vidriduch's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29828363/124319) is the most appropriate. This is probably not the only part of your code that requires Date manipulations (even though the one you showed is particulary easy to code). You should seriously consider using existing, tested Date libraries.

Comment: I don't know javascript, but doesn't it have a hashmap, like Python's dictionary or C++'s std::map?

Comment: @Happy check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29828180/1673391) using JavaScript object

Comment: Isn't this suppose to be for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: So many answers changing the behavior of the code by not taking the default '' into account which results in undefined output, which is different as what the original does.

Comment: @Loko cool thanks for that link, didn't know about that substack? Neat... so many awesome answers here :) I've gotten to a point where I'm trying to optimize everywhere, even `switch case` statements to replace an if else that has 3 checks... using `ternary` functions where I can etc etc...

Comment: This is **not** a duplicate question >:( this is asking a completely different question, the answer may be the same however.

Comment: @LeonGaban completely agree. And since you have just passed 3k rep you can now vote to reopen above!

Comment: (Actually I didn't cop you were the OP - you could have cast a reopen vote at 250 rep :-)

Comment: Hehe, yeah I didn't know I could do that, but I just cast my vote :) perhaps I should edit my title, however I feel the added info is useful. Either way I think this help lot of devs.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Define an array, then get by index.

```
var months = ['January', 'February', ...];

var month = months[mm - 1] || '';
```

Comment: instead of `mm - 1` you can also set `undefined` as the first value (index 0) so the array indices will match month numbers

Comment: @Touffy Yes, this is just personal taste :)

Comment: `var month = month[(mm -1) % 12]`

Comment: @mpez0 I think I'd prefer knowing that someone's managed to come up with month number 15, rather than hide what is probably bad data

Comment: @Touffy I think I'd stick with `mm-1`, so that `months.length==12`.

Comment: As the poster said, it's really just a matter of taste. There's no immediate practical use to having length==12 since you can safely hardcode it.

Comment: @Touffy I would argue that's not a matter of taste, but a matter of [avoiding clever code](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/91854/how-to-train-yourself-to-avoid-writing-clever-code). Imagine yourself reading some else's `[undefined, 'January', 'February', ...]` - I best your first reaction is _WTF?!_, which is usually not a good sign...

Comment: @Touffy Re hard coding `length==12`, not a good idea either, at most simplify to `months.length` (your suggestion already makes for `month.length==13`, gotcha ...)

Comment: Wouldn't `['January' = 1, 'February', ...]` work here like in some other languages? I'm new to JS ;P

Comment: @miraculixx I may be cleverer than the ideal strawman programmer used in this example, but my reaction would be that, considering the contents and name of the array, it's very obvious what's going on. And I'm not suggesting assigning 12 to `months.length`, but hard-coding the value 12 instead when you want to compare something to the number of months in a year.

Comment: @CarlesAlcolea even with the correct syntax, what you suggest would be indexed the wrong way around (you'd have to lookup the month number in a loop instead of just accessing the month name by its number).

Comment: @CupawnTae makes a valid point about change in behaviour in their answer below.

Comment: @izkata Translating the 200th month of my 25-year time series, modulo works well.

Comment: @PieterB That would be very easy to fix it :)

Comment: @Touffy you do realize that your 'obvious' fact that there are only 12 months in the array is at odds with your suggestion to have an undefined element at index 0? If experience tells me anything, nothing is obvious unless you know, and any code that assumes the future reader has the same insight as the current programmer is notoriously hard to change due to all the hidden obviousness...

Comment: Or a hashmap, with key/values: '1'=>'January', '2'=>'February', et al

Comment: @Touffy A pedantic note: using `undefined` as the first value more closely preserves the original behaviour. As this answer is currently written, the subtraction in `months[mm - 1]` forces `mm` to be parsed as an integer, such that `'03'` also gets converted to `'March'`. (That might actually be desirable, but it's technically not what the OP asked.)

Comment: BTW, you don't need to write that `undefined`: `[ , 'January', ...` is the same as `[undefined, 'January', ...`

Answer (score 82):

what about not to use array at all :)

```
var objDate = new Date("10/11/2009"),
    locale = "en-us",
    month = objDate.toLocaleString(locale, { month: "long" });

console.log(month);

// or if you want the shorter date: (also possible to use "narrow" for "O"
console.log(objDate.toLocaleString(locale, { month: "short" }));
```

as per this answer [Get month name from Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643320/get-month-name-from-date) from David Storey

Comment: Given the problem statement in question, your answer is not really solving that problem but some different solution which might be correct in a different context. Selected answer is still the best and most efficient.

Comment: Only ``new Date("2009-11-10")`` format is guaranteed to be parsed (see this specifiation: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm). Other date formats (including one in your answer) may be parsed if browser chooses so, and hence are not portable.

Answer (score 59):

Try this:

```
var months = {'1': 'January', '2': 'February'}; //etc
var month = months[mm];
```

Note that `mm` can be an integer or a string and it will still work.

If you want non-existing keys to result in empty string `''` (instead of `undefined`), then add this line:

```
month = (month == undefined) ? '' : month;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s4d4rhf2/1/).

Comment: On larger datasets than "months of the year"   this will probably be more efficient.

Comment: This is effectively an enum (i.e. make it immutable), define it as
`var months = Object.freeze({'1': 'January', '2': 'February'}); //etc`
See [Enums in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5040502/1796930)

Comment: @Alexander If you swap the key and values, then yes it's similar to an enum.

Answer (score 26):

You could create an array instead and lookup the month name:

```
var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']


var month = months[mm-1] || '';
```

See the answer by @CupawnTae for the rational behind the code `|| ''`

Comment: rather than start with 0 index you could keep `undefined` at `0`  as `var months = [ undefined, 'January','February','March', .....` In this way you will use `month = months[mm];`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: please avoid 'clever' code. The next person's first reaction whould be wtf. It's only a '-1',  months.Length will then be 13, wtf^2. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/91854/how-to-train-yourself-to-avoid-writing-clever-code

Answer (score 19):

Be careful!

The thing that should immediately trigger alarm bells is the first line: `var month = '';` - why is this variable being initialized to an empty string, rather than `null` or `undefined`? It may just have been habit or copy/pasted code, but unless you know that for sure, it is not safe to ignore it when you're refactoring code.

If you use an array of month names and change your code to `var month = months[mm-1];` you are changing the behaviour, because now for numbers outside the range, or non-numeric values, `month` will be `undefined`. You may know that this is ok, but there are many situations where this would be bad.

For example, let's say your `switch` is in a function `monthToName(mm)`, and someone is calling your function like this:

```
var monthName = monthToName(mm);

if (monthName === '') {
  alert("Please enter a valid month.");
} else {
  submitMonth(monthName);
}
```

Now if you change to using an array and returning `monthName[mm-1]`, the calling code will no longer function as intended, and it will submit `undefined` values when it is supposed to display a warning. I'm not saying this is *good* code, but unless you know exactly how the code is being used, you can't make assumptions.

Or maybe the original initialization was there because some code further down the line assumes that `month` will always be a string, and does something like `month.length` - this will result in an exception being thrown for invalid months and potentially kill the calling script completely.

If you *do* know the entire context - e.g. it's all your own code, and no-one else is ever going to use it, *and* you trust yourself not forget you made the change sometime in the future - it may be safe to change the behaviour like this, but soooo many bugs come from this kind of assumption that in real life you're far better off programming defensively and/or documenting the behaviour thoroughly.

[Wasmoo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29830464/1469259) gets it right *(EDIT: a number of other answers, including the accepted one, have now been fixed too)* - you can use `months[mm-1] || ''` or if you would prefer to make it more obvious at a glance what's happening, something like:

```
var months = ['January', 'February', ...];

var month;

if (mm >= 1 && m <= 12) {
  month = months[mm - 1];
} else {
  month = ''; // empty string when not a valid month
}
```

Comment: Nobody else has mentioned the change in behaviour yet, so this should be taken into account when re-factoring code.

Comment: This answer is spot on. Most of the other answers change the behavior of the code in a subtle way. This may not matter or it may become that irritatingly hard to find bug.

Comment: Ah so it's always best to init a var to `undefined`? Does that save performance if the type gets converted?

Comment: @LeonGaban it's not about performance: the original question initialized the variable to an empty string and left it at that if no valid month was selected, whereas a lot of the other answers here ignored that fact and changed the behaviour by returning `undefined` when the input wasn't `1..12`. Except in *very* exceptional circumstances, correct behaviour trumps performance every time.

Answer (score 17):

For completeness I'd like to supplement to current answers. Basically, you can ommit the `break` keyword and directly return an appropriate value. This tactic is useful if the value cannot be stored in a precomputed look-up table.

```
function foo(mm) {
    switch(mm) {
        case '1':  return 'January';
        case '2':  return 'February';
        case '3':  return 'March';
        case '4':  return 'April';
        // [...]
        case '12': return 'December';
    }
    return '';
}
```

Once again, using a look-up table or date functions is more succinct and subjectively *better*.

Answer (score 16):

You could do it using an array:

```
var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 
              'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 
              'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

var month = months[mm - 1] || '';
```

Answer (score 12):

Here's another option that uses only 1 variable and still applies the default value `''` when `mm` is outside of range.

```js
var month = ['January', 'February', 'March',
             'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
             'August', 'September', 'October',
             'November', 'December'
            ][mm-1] || '';
```

Comment: Range checking, and throwing an exception could work also. And returning "Error", or "Undefined" might be alternative to the empty string.

Answer (score 9):

You could write it as an expression instead of a switch, using conditional operators:

```
var month =
  mm == 1 ? 'January' :
  mm == 2 ? 'February' :
  mm == 3 ? 'March' :
  mm == 4 ? 'April' :
  mm == 5 ? 'May' :
  mm == 6 ? 'June' :
  mm == 7 ? 'July' :
  mm == 8 ? 'August' :
  mm == 9 ? 'September' :
  mm == 10 ? 'October' :
  mm == 11 ? 'November' :
  mm == 12 ? 'December' :
  '';
```

If you haven't seen chained conditional operators before this may seem harder to read at first. Writing it as an expression makes one aspect even easier to see than the original code; it's clear that the intention of the code is to assign a value to the variable `month`.

Comment: I meant to suggest this one as well. It's actually very readable while remaining concise, and would work well for sparse mappings and non-numeric keys, which the array solution doesn't. PS I got a random unexplained downvote on my answer too - probably the same drive-by artist.

Answer (score 6):

Building on [Cupawn Tae's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29844172/4845042) answer previous I'd shorten it to :

```
var months = ['January', 'February', ...];
var month = (mm >= 1 && mm <= 12) ? months[mm - 1] : '';
```

Alternatively, yes, I appreciate, less readable:

```
var month = months[mm - 1] || ''; // as mentioned further up
```

Comment: You can skip `(!!months[mm - 1])` and simply do `months[mm - 1]`.

Comment: That would result in undefined if the array index was out of range!

Comment: `months[mm - 1]` will return `undefined` for an index that is out of range. Since `undefined` is falsy you will end up with `''` as the value of `month`.

Comment: As stated in other answers you can simplify this line even more:
`var month = months[mm - 1] || '';`

Comment: Although I've noticed further up (wasn't around when I posted),
   var month = months[mm - 1] || '';
Which would be neater still.

Comment: OK your initial response was unclear I now see we're coming from the same place with this ;)
bear in mind I was being mindful of the initial questions "[...] but still easily readable?" which is quite subjective.

Answer (score 5):

Like @vidriduch, I would like to underline the importance of i20y ("internationalisability") of code in nowadays' context and suggest the following concise and robust solution together with the unitary test.

```js
function num2month(month, locale) {
    if (month != Math.floor(month) || month < 1 || month > 12)
        return undefined;
    var objDate = new Date(Math.floor(month) + "/1/1970");
    return objDate.toLocaleString(locale, {month: "long"});
}

/* Test/demo */
for (mm = 1; mm <= 12; mm++)
    document.writeln(num2month(mm, "en") + " " +
                     num2month(mm, "ar-lb") + "<br/>");
document.writeln(num2month("x", "en") + "<br/>");
document.writeln(num2month(.1, "en") + "<br/>");
document.writeln(num2month(12.5, "en" + "<br/>"));
```

I try to stay as close as possible to the original question, i.e. transform numbers 1 to 12 into month names, not only for one special case, but return `undefined` in case of invalid arguments, using some of the formerly added criticism to and contents of other answers. 
(The change from `undefined` to `''` is trivial, in case *exact* matching is needed.)

Answer (score 4):

```
var getMonth=function(month){
   //Return string to number.
    var strMonth = ['January', 'February', 'March',
             'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
             'August', 'September', 'October',
             'November', 'December'
            ];
    //return number to string.
    var intMonth={'January':1, 'February':2, 'March':3,
             'April':4, 'May':5, 'June':6, 'July':7,
             'August':8, 'September':9, 'October':10,
             'November':11, 'December':12
            };
    //Check type and return 
    return (typeof month === "number")?strMonth[month-1]:intMonth[month]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for [**wasmoo**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1017294/wasmoo)'s solution, but adjust it like this :

```
var month = [
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
    'October',
    'November',
    'December'
][mm-1] || '';
```

It is the exact same code, really, but differently indented, which IMO makes it more readable.