# How to use Enum annotation from JSDoc in Object properties

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, comments, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I started to use more often the jsdocs and I searched around how to use the enum type and still a doubt about it.

Here are the usage definition at JSDocs: [Enum definition at JSDocs](https://jsdoc.app/tags-enum.html)
The example showed is about a single enum object, how it would work if I have an Object which one specific field is an Enum type ?

Consider that Im using the sequelize orm and the definition it is about a Model.

For example.

```
/**
* @name Car
* @typedef {Object} Car - This is a car Model.
* @property {string} type - Enum type.
* @property {string} color - This is an attribute for car's color
*/
const Car = {
  // This should be considered as an enum type of strings.
  type: {
    type: ENUM,
    values: ['0', '1'],
    defaultValue: '0',
  },
  color: { 
    type: STRING,
    defaultValue: 'color',
  }
}
```

So, that way that I think that should work it would be like (which is not so fancy):

```
{ 
  ...
  /**
    * @enum
  */
  type: {
    type: ENUM,
    values: ['0', '1'],
    defaultValue: '0',
  },
  ...
}
```

I was wondering if have some option which works like:

```
/**
* @name Car
* @typedef {Object} Car - This is a car Model.
* @property {string} type - Enum type.
* @enum
* @default 'Car1'
* @property {string} color - This is an attribute for car's color
*/
```

Someone have some suggestion about it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287903/what-is-the-preferred-syntax-for-defining-enums-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

If you have a type inside a type separate your enum from car model and reference it there. i think this way you can use JSDoc enum.

```
const CarType = {
 CarType1: 'CarType1',
 CarType2: 'CarType2',
}

const Car = {
  type: CarType
  color: 'some string',
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put some informations. But would you recommend to split into two objects, which the first one it would be considered an Enum type ?

Comment: Yes i think you should separate your enum type from your model and then reference that type in car model