# How to convert a JavaScript Symbol to a string without the "Symbol(" prefix?

Tags: javascript

For example, if I use `toString()`:

```js
let s = Symbol('abc')
console.log(s.toString())
```

I get:

```
'Symbol(abc)'
```

How to get just the:

```
'abc'
```

part instead?

I know how to do this with string manipulation, but I would hope for a potentially more efficient solution that directly obtains the value.

I am using `Symbol` to implement an `Enum`: [What is the preferred syntax for defining enums in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287903/what-is-the-preferred-syntax-for-defining-enums-in-javascript/30058506#30058506) and want to serialize it with a `toJSON()` on the containing class.

Tested in Node.js v10.15.1.

Comment: `.slice` the string?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I would hope for a solution that does not involve possibly inefficient string manipulation.

Comment: Slicing a string isn't inefficient at all. If you're running into performance issues, run a performance test to identify parts of your script that are taking up resources - string slicing will almost certainly not be one of them. (Worrying about it is quite premature optimization)

Answer (score 7):

Use description to get value

```
s.description
```

As when we create Symbol we pass description of that symbol.

For more [read this.](https://javascript.info/symbol)

Answer (score 5):

I would use `s.description`. It will return the *description* of the `Symbol`.

A deeper explanation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/description).

Comment: in later browsers only (not even edge)

Comment: @Bravo yes, seems not standardized yet from the "stage 4" proposal part of the page? But good to know.

Comment: it will become standard - but you know it won't work in anything from Microsoft

Comment: @Bravo ... not until the Chromium based version of Edge is released anyway.