# compressor for javascript and css

Tags: javascript, css, compression

What compressor is the best for javascript and css minified ? I am using YUI compressor , now. Any other best than YUI compressor ?

Comment: Duplicate: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932/best-javascript-compressor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For JavaScript you could check for your self via the [CompressorRater](http://compressorrater.thruhere.net/).

Another JavaScript compressor to note is the one that Google uses [closure](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home), checkout [this article](http://code.google.com/speed/articles/compressing-javascript.html), which is not featured there.

Comment: can compress CSS ? I can't find it ? Do you know css compressor ? closure is a another great tool for JS ;)

Comment: CompressorRater is only for JavaScript, checkout various links on css compression and pick your favorite (I'm using Yahoo's YUI compressor):
http://designshack.co.uk/articles/css/18-css-compression-tools-and-techniques
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/
http://www.phpied.com/cssmin-js/
http://www.cssdrive.com/index.php/main/csscompressor/

Comment: oh! great.. http://designshack.co.uk/articles/css/18-css-compression-tools-and-techniques

Answer (score 2):

I like [Shrinksafe](http://shrinksafe.dojotoolkit.org/)

> Many other tools also shrink
>   JavaScript files, but ShrinkSafe is
>   different. Instead of relying on
>   brittle regular expressions,
>   ShrinkSafe is based on Rhino, a
>   JavaScript interpreter. This allows
>   ShrinkSafe to transform the source of
>   a file with much more confidence that
>   the resulting script will function
>   identically to the file you uploaded.

For CSS you can use [Minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [JSMin](http://fmarcia.info/jsmin/test.html) service. I don't know if it's better or worse then YUI Compressor but it works well.

Comment: JSmin can compress CSS ?

Answer (score 0):

try http://shrinker.ch . it uses yuicompresspor for css files and google closure for javascript + some kind of magic.