# Makefile to combine js files and make a compressed version

Tags: javascript, build, makefile, compression

I am trying to write a basic makefile that combines multiple js files into a single one and then does the same but compresses them.

So far I have this one that can make the compressed version fine.

```
# Set the source directory
srcdir = src/

# Create the list of modules
modules =   ${srcdir}core.js\
            ${srcdir}sizzle.js\
            ${srcdir}json2.js\
            ${srcdir}ajax.js\
            ${srcdir}attribute.js\
            ${srcdir}content.js\
            ${srcdir}cookie.js\
            ${srcdir}css.js\
            ${srcdir}event.js\
            ${srcdir}json.js\
            ${srcdir}location.js\
            ${srcdir}opacity.js\
            ${srcdir}ready.js\
            ${srcdir}size.js\
            ${srcdir}init.js

# Compress all of the modules into spark.js
spark.js: ${modules}
    java -jar yuicompressor.jar -o $@ $^
```

Does anyone know how I would go about adding an uncompressed version called spark-dev.js? I have been trying to use cat but I didn't get very far. This is my first makefile I have ever written.

**EDIT**
I tried this code with cat

```
spark-dev.js: ${modules}
    cat $@ $^
```

Comment: How, specifically, did you try to use cat? And what went wrong?

Comment: @slowdog I have put the code I tried in my edit.

Comment: @slowdog Oh, and as to what went wrong, it echoed the contents of all the files then printed: 'make: *** [spark-dev.js] Error 1'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You were almost there :-) This should work:

```
spark-dev.js: ${modules}
    cat > $@ $^
```

Background: The function of `cat` is to (try to) open all the files listed on its command line, and dump the contents to stdout. The `> $@` syntax is understood by the shell to mean "create the file `$@`, and connect this command's stdout to it", so now we end up with the contents of `$^` combined together into `$@`.

Comment: Hmm, stopped it printing the contents, but it is now throwing this error: 'makefile:23: *** missing separator. Stop.'

Comment: Make sure you have a tab character, not spaces, at the start of the line with the `cat` command. Copypasting makefile fragments in and out of browsers is a pain because the tabs tend to magically turn into spaces...

Comment: Okay, now it is working, but only executing the first command, is there a way of executing both?

Comment: If you put the line `all: spark.js spark-dev.js` near the top of the makefile (before the other two rules), then `make` will build both output files by default.