# Make File for Javascript

Tags: javascript, deployment, makefile

Can somebody tell me how can i use make files to combine and merge different javascript files. I have seen many different projects using different javascript files and later on merge by using MAKE utility.

Deep.

Comment: I use ant for this purpose, if you're interested I can share my script.

Comment: You can take a look at [jQuery's Makefile](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/Makefile).

Comment: Merge as in appending one to another, or something more sophisticated? Do you know how to merge these files manually, from the command line?

Comment: There’s a pretty nice tutorial here: https://blog.jcoglan.com/2014/02/05/building-javascript-projects-with-make/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Makefile to combine js files and make a compressed version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413903/makefile-to-combine-js-files-and-make-a-compressed-version)