# Variables when minified

Tags: javascript, minify

Given that when minified JavaScript variables will be simplified *what is* the best way to declare or use the variable for window, document, undefined, etc.?

1st way

```
(function ($, win, doc, undefined) {
}(jQuery, window, document));
```

2nd way

```
(function () {
    var $ = jQuery,
        win = window,
        doc = document,
        undefined;
}());
```

Comment: It seems like, as the goal of minifying is to drop the filesize, the best answer would be the 1st because it is shorter.

Comment: The 2nd way is better for its readability. Many tools are available to minify the code that can compact the code than in 1st way.

Comment: @KunJ see what I said in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20876289/2709301).

Comment: @TJonS I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For minified code, shorter (less bytes to be transferred) is always better.  So, for a minified file the first option would be best:

`(function($,w,d,u){})(jQuery,window,document);`  **46 characters.**

Compared to the other option:

`(function(){var $=jQuery,w=window,d=document,u=undefined;})();`  **62 characters.**

<sup>P.S. You did your closures wrong.  `(function(){}())` will throw a syntax error.  `(function(){})()` won't.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter, write your code keeping a legible and maintainable format, and for production then use a [minifier](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) that will shrink your code to something really small.

You can even automatize the whole process by using something like [make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413903/makefile-to-combine-js-files-and-make-a-compressed-version)

Keep in mind that [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) (you're trying to minimize the size of your code beforehand)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it really makes a difference, except that the second way takes up more space. I personally prefer the second way, as I think it is more readable.

But for minifying, you DEFINITELY want to go with the first way. Much less space used.