# JavaScript compressor

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-framework

Can you suggest good, free of charge tools (ideally with a command line interface) to compress JavaScript code?

I will take experiences and tips in to consideration when selecting the best tool.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best JavaScript compressor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932/best-javascript-compressor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Google Closure Compiler](https://code.google.com/closure/compiler/) is fairly popular.

Answer (score 3):

[YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) is a good one that's maintained by Yahoo!

Answer (score 1):

[UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS/) is pretty nice. If you have node.js+npm installed, just do `npm install -g uglify-js` then use the 'uglifyjs' command.

It achieves similar or better compression than Closure Compiler, with less danger of mangling your code, and is very fast.