# Which is the best javascript minifier UglifyJS or YUI compressor?

Tags: javascript, minify, yui-compressor, uglifyjs, uglifyjs2

Please provide me which is fast and best compressor for Javascript. I have shortlisted these two for my application. Please tell me if you know another best compressor.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question has been asked and discussed a million times, please do not start a new question like that... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520285/is-there-a-good-javascript-minifier        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932/best-javascript-compressor

Comment: Hi GEMI, I have asked best between UglifyJS and YUI Compressor. Neither of your links provide solution for that. If you have those links then tell me. and Please read question carefully first then comment, If you know that why don't you post the answer.

Comment: You also said `Please tell me if you know another best compressor`. Furthermore, `Neither of your links provide solution for that.` - there is no solution for this type of question since your criteria of `fast and best` are subjective terms.

Comment: +1 nothing wrong with this qu

Comment: Thanks FutuToad, There is no WORD call "Stupid question". I dont know why previously GEMI reacted so wrongly on this. As I seen this question helped a lot people. Some time lot of restriction SUFFOCATE the USERS. I like google groups more now.

Comment: @JSRocker: I don't participate in this discussion. Just want to say that a total vote-count of 5 (2 down and 3 up at the time of writing) is not really much, so "helped a lot of people" is slightly exaggerated.

Comment: The best part is that STACK OVERFLOW blocked my account for this reason and not letting me post new questions.
I mean this is really amazing now. Thats why I can clearly see why people move to other forums for the specific kind of support. As there are already forums for dedicated frameworks likes for ExtJS, AngularJS, NodeJS, etc.

Keep spreading suffocation in your environment. All the best :)

Comment: @JSRocker (un)fortunately stackoverflow is not for this type of questions you ask. They're not containing specific questions neither possible hints how would you measure the "bestness". It's a bit unprofessional from your side to reply so hatereded to GEMI as well - he dropped useful links. But I agree, SO users sometimes suffer on illusory superiority (unfortunately). It's not the place to discuss personalities anyway - be professional, collect info on your question, measure and turn on the mind before asking questions on SO, that's it. Good luck with "no evil" forums though!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Question does not contain criteria for 'Best' :) If you ask me about simple - here is one:
JS Miinifyer (http://jscompress.com/)

- This is simple - copy paste your JS and get the output.
- This checks syntax - it will not compress if there are syntax errors 
  (at least some level of checking I am not sure if it checks details.)
- You can upload JS files also instead of just copy paste.

We used this for our productions deployments to do:
1. Compression.
2. Uglify JS

Comment: JSCompress uses UglifyJS internally.

Comment: This answer only promotes a website and does not say anything about a javascript compressor